# On-topic self promotion

Tags: discussion, spam

Have a look at [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202722/pat-gonzalez). Everything he posts is a link to one of his tutorials. However, it's always on-topic (as far as I can tell). Three of his posts are flagged as spam (the count is 3 votes each at this moment). He also has all of ONE up vote across 35 answers.

**Is this really spam?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He isn't trying to sell anything and I don't see any advertising posted. Not seeing how this is spam especially if he is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

As of 6/7/16, according to the Stack Exchange Meta rules on "Promotion", specifically ["How to not be a spammer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) (emphasis not mine):

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

Although he's on topic, he is not disclosing his affiliation with the website or tutorials, so he is breaking the rules. So it's *technically* spam, or at least spamm-able.

(As far as I know, every Stack Exchange site has this same exact page about "How to not be a spammer"...and all of the rules for the most part)

Comment: related FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way I like the accepted answer (because I wrote it) so check his answers against those 4 bullets and if they fail, comment with a link there asking him to edit his answer into shape.

Answer (score 0):

I donno... If he *is* on-topic, then he surely isn't contributing much (considering his 1/35 vote/answer ratio...)!

I'm inclined to call it spam.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be more worried if the answers were getting a lot of votes.  As it is, it seems like the community generally either recognizes what's going on or has an appropriate opinion of the library in question.  As it is, with no one voting for him I think we can just give it some time and he'll get bored and move on.  Removing his posts is just likely to induce him to hang around longer.