# Self promotion answers that actually answer the question: Are they spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I saw this answer:

[Should I write my own licensing program or are there any good, ready made solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189354/should-i-write-my-own-licensing-program-or-are-there-any-good-ready-made-solutio/3196583#3196583)

where the poster is trying to solicit a user for his product.   His answer though, is on topic and appropriate.

Is this spam?   I'm inclined to think not.

Should we remove/edit user contact info and just leave the product link?  Maybe?

Should we do nothing? ???

I saw related question: [On-topic self promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/on-topic-self-promotion) but this is different because I believe this poster *is* trying to sell something.

Comment: Some reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10174/using-so-sf-su-to-promote-your-products, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46793/problem-user-spamming-personal-library, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47994/help-this-poor-spammer-out. Offering products as an answer is a perfectly acceptable practice as long as it is on-topic, provides full disclosure, addresses the question, and isn't just copy-paste. Personally speaking, it's sometimes the very answer you need, after all.