# Self Promotion Rules

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I have been using Stack Overflow for some time now and find it a great Q&A site where I have got a lot of help and, I hope, have been able to give back something from time to time.  I am now thinking of

1. completing the answer to one of my own unanswered questions with a link back to one of my own sites where I offer the missing utility (for free) to handle the task I queried about
2. Providing as an answer to an existing question by another Stack Overflow user a link to one of my own sites. I should mention that the original question is more than a year old.  I should also mention that one of the answers links to another product which is now a commercial offering whilst the link I would provide is to a product that is still in beta and it is in fact a fully relevant answer to the question "in question".

If either or both of these are going to go down badly with the Stack Overflow community then I simply will not do what I have in mind.  In any case, I thought it best to check first.

Comment: Self-promotion is largely valid, if kept to a reasonable level and is fully disclosed. Apply some common sense, don't spam, fully disclose how you are related to the products, and you *should* be fine.

Comment: Oh, and to add - if the answer contains *just* the disclosure and a link to the project, it will probably rather quickly be deleted as a Link Only Answer. Doing as you're suggesting - building out existing answers with further information - should be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks.  With my own question the only answers I was given were inadequate since the utility I was seeking didn't actually exist - at least not to the knowledge of the SO members that saw the question. With the other question (not from me) there are a few answers many of which provide links to 3rd party, paid-for, services.  If I were to provide my own link I think it would enrich that set of answers and provide readers, and the person who asked the question, a wider field of options to choose from.

Comment: It might help the reader find another, better tool, but shopping questions are unsuitable for Stack Overflow to begin with - therefore (new) answers to (old) shopping questions are likely to be removed if they contain little else than a link. Elaborate about *why* your tool is better, if you feel the need to answer that type of question - provide some cool code that targets the specific problem, explain, help. =)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll bear all that in mind.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56150/self-promotion-answers-that-actually-answer-the-question-are-they-spam?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion?rq=1