# How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?

Tags: discussion, faq, hyperlinks, self-promotion, external-sources

I would like to help my fellow Stackizens, using material from my blog or other website.  But external links are sometimes viewed as excessive promotion.  From the FAQ:

> Be careful, because the community
>   frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as
>   spam. Post good, relevant answers, and
>   if they happen to be about your
>   product or website, so be it. However,
>   you must disclose your affiliation in
>   your answers. Also, if a huge
>   percentage of your posts include a
>   mention of your product or website,
>   you're probably here for the wrong
>   reasons.

I have tried posting answers that reference my blog, and I have followed the above rules, but my answers still get flagged as spam.  How can I craft an answer that references my blog, website or other resource, but is still acceptable to the community?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In my experience, posts with links are not downvoted if all these conditions are met:

- you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
- you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
- **someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all**
- you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile

For example:

> You can use the CircularLabelsStyle
> custom property for this, for example:
>
> ```
>   chart1.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Circular";
> ```
>
> I [blogged
> about this last year](http://example.com), with some sample
> code.

The other extreme, an answer that says nothing more than "here" or "read this" or "please read" and is a link, I will not just downvote but flag as not an answer, and I don't care whether it's the definitive documentation from the owner of the technology, another question on the same SE site, or just a blog you wrote yourself.

Comment: **Rule of thumb:** Can your post stand on its own, or does it require clicking the link to be meaningful?

Comment: Links can also be used as references. For example: "You can parse (x)html with regex, provided the regex engine uses extended perl regexes according to [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)"

Comment: Btw. one could print the external references smaller using `<sup>` html tags. That would probably further underline that the content of the small print is further resources, not the main answer.

Answer (score 7):

From an [answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315964/1677912) by George Stocker, this is some good guidance for writing an answer that recommends an external resource (emphasis mine):

> A good answer that involves an off-site resource references the
>   following:
>
> - What is this thing you're talking about?
> - Where do I install it?
> - How do I install it?
> - How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question?
> - **Are you affiliated** with this thing in any way, shape, or form?