# Why were all my answers deleted?

Tags: support

I answered a question about using GWT to develop mobile apps, but it was deleted. The information can not be found in other places, and there was no explanation as to why it was deleted. Seems like a very unfriendly community, I don't think I'll ever try to answer anything on Stack Overflow again.

[Here is my post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344983/396458)

> If you are used to developing with the MVP pattern or want to make a mobile version of an existing app, I would suggest to use m-gwt http://www.m-gwt.com/ M-gwt works well with GWT best practices, such as MVP and tries to only extend the core of GWT with necessary functionality for mobiles.
>
> If you are used to developing iPhone apps, you can have a look at nextinterfaces.com. However, next interfaces uses it's own MVC system, so it doesn't work well with MVP or for making mobile versions of existing GWT sites.
>
> Then there is also GwtMobile code.google.com/p/gwtmobile/ GwtMobile is similar to m-gwt, but uses it's own Page system instead of the built-in GWT Places, so its also more difficult to use together with existing GWT code. GwtMobile has some nice widgets that can also be used with other frameworks. It also has its own persistence framework.
>
> M-gwt and GwtMobile both have their own Phonegap binding so that you can upload the apps to Apple app store and Android market.
>
> Gwt-mobile-webkit is currently not so much about mobile as the only thing that is usable and not currently integrated in core GWT is the Database API. If you need Web SQL, then gwt-mobile-webkit Database API is your friend code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/
>
> If you want very simple no-frills widgets and no animations, but compatibility with stone age browsers, then have a look at informagen.org/mobile-gwt/ The code is hidden away at informagen.org/maven/org/informagen/gwt/mobile-gwt/1.1.1/

I also answered another question about suggestions how to make a mobile version of an existing GWT app, this was also deleted:

> The mobile framework for GWT that currently is most close to core GWT is m-gwt. M-gwt has mobile versions of many of the core GWT widgets, so it's useful easily making a mobile version of existing GWT apps.
>
> There are other mobile frameworks, but converting an existing app will be more work because most of them use their own custom way of transitioning between pages, so you'd have to do more rewriting. For example in GwtMobile you use this.goTo(newPage) instead of standard activities and places.

Comment: Can you give us a question the answer was deleted from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166554/detecting-mobile-browser-in-gwt/8344983

Comment: FWIW, as an outsider who doesn't know much about the topic on that question, your answer _sounds_ like some serious spam advertisement more than a legitimate answer.  The kind where you see the same phrase and words repeated over and over.  It might have helped if you didn't word it in that manner.

Comment: @Jeff: and that was the *best* answer.

Comment: Note that your first example answer *doesn't actually answer the question that was asked,* which is *"How can my web application detect that it is running on a mobile device?"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That post was flagged as looking like a promotional piece (spam).  I thought it was borderline and other moderators agreed, but then I saw two other posts by you that did nothing but promote *that* post.

> I have written about different mobile frameworks for GWT in my answer here [Detecting mobile browser in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166554/detecting-mobile-browser-in-gwt/8344983#8344983).

When four of your five answers mention a specific product, and two of those are exact duplicates that only link to your other answer, it looks a little fishy.  I did undelete the original answer, but please take the [guidelines posted by Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114403/1288) into consideration in the future.

Comment: I see. I guess I should have worded it differently.

Comment: It might be a good idea for a mod to leave a comment on the answer reflecting that it is declared a valid answer and not spam.  Just in case future would-be flaggers might not be so hasty.  I just saw another downvote on it which probably came from another spam flag.

Comment: @user1040248 Yes, you might want to rephrase it, since it has already drawn another spam flag in the few minutes since I undeleted it.

Comment: What kind of words should I avoid so that posts are not flagged as spam?

Comment: My best advice is to avoid library recommendation questions (they are not constructive questions anyway), and post answers that *address specifically the question being asked.* You should also read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Happy hunting, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @user1040248 Try to directly answer the question instead of adding stuff that's not actually relevant to the question, making it sound overly promotional.

Comment: I thought the answer was relevant for this question though, I have also updated the answer now. But you should not link to other answers from a question, or? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049020/using-gwt-on-mobile-phone

Comment: @user1040248 Answers really should stand on their own without requiring the reader to follow a link, so no you shouldn't just link to another answer.  It's fine to link to anything as a reference, but the text of your answer should be able to stand on its own without the link.

Answer (score 13):

We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website. Per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion):

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

Any type of "astroturfing" promotion is not acceptable.  It brings down the overall value of genuine recommendations for everyone on the site.

If you can stay within the above guidelines, and offer questions and answers of genuine benefit to the community which happen to mention your affiliation or product in context -- and with full disclosure -- then your future contributions are welcome.

Comment: I don't have any affiliations with any of the product. My post is the result of about a month of research into the current GWT mobile libraries. To be honest, I strongly prefer one of the libraries, m-get, since the other ones tend to implement stuff themselves that already exists in core GWT. In my experience that just made it more difficult to use, since I couldn't easily use GWT best practices like MVP.

Comment: Then have a look at this meta post: [How do I properly write an answer that references my blog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-do-i-properly-write-an-answer-that-references-my-blog)

Comment: I need to set up a blog to post an answer?

Comment: In general, answers *need to be capable of standing on their own.* Linking to an external resource is fine, but if the link is the only thing in the answer, it's not really an answer.  In the future, if you want to refer to an external resource, *include a summary of the material at the link* so that users don't have to click the link to benefit from your answer.

Comment: I don't have a blog. I posted links to the websites of the different libraries

Comment: The links I included were only meant to make it easier for people to find the websites of each of the libraries

Comment: @Robert - looks like he's just pushing a library he really likes.  Assuming the library is germane to the questions he answering, is this really any different from answers telling users to use jQuery when they ask questions about **complicated** dom manipulation?

Comment: So I could post the answer again if I rewrite it and don't make it sound like I prefer any of the libraries over the others?

Comment: @AdamRackis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234436/what-options-for-mobile-support-are-there-for-a-large-gwt-web-application/8345865#8345865 -- Closing as Not Constructive.

Comment: @AdamRackis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946652/good-mobile-oriented-gwt-widget-library-alternatives/8345709#8345709 is very old.  What's the point of plugging a library there?

Comment: @AdamRackis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049020/using-gwt-on-mobile-phone/8345797#8345797 - Posted a link-only answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166554/detecting-mobile-browser-in-gwt/8344983#8344983 - Posted a wall of text advertising the plugin (and several others), but *didn't answer the OP's specific question.*

Comment: @Robert - fair enough, I should have given the SO team more of the benefit of the doubt.  I should have known they wouldn't delete answers without a good reason.

Comment: I was just trying to make it easier to get an overview of the current mobile GWT libraries. What I could find on Google was mostly old posts or links to Stack Overflow questions that were in many cases old. Of course it is my subjective opinion, and I know that others have completely different opinions, for example the developer of next interfaces made his own way of doing things that already exist in core GWT, because he thinks Googles way of doing things is more cumbersome.

Comment: @user1040248 That's not necessary, as long as it answers the question (you can help your case by linking to specific parts of the library's docs that are pertinent to the question). I suggest specific libraries all the time.

Comment: Of course some of the questions you were answering aren't constructive to begin with, but in this case I find it hard to blame you (considering you are new to the site)

Comment: @RobertHarvey From the question text "do you have any suggestion for implementing such application in GWT?" That's what I answered.