# What differentiates good links from bad links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, faq-proposed

What are some good examples that can be used to explain the difference between:

1. positive, informative, and useful links that improve the quality of an answer; and
2. links which are unconstructive or unwelcome in the Stack Overflow community?

Concrete but widely-applicable examples are welcome. Remember, the idea is to provide general guidance, not keel-haul people who've made linking mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What Links (Should Be) For

Links (other than duplicate/related links) are primarily for:

1. definitions
2. references
3. supporting documentation

Links should not stand in lieu of other content in an answer.

#### Good Example

Here, the link might point to some canonical source (perhaps the GNU Bash Manual) that provides an official definition of "shell glob." The page still provides a *local* answer to the question.

```
You could use a [shell glob][1] for this.

    ls *
```

#### Bad Example

Here, the "answer" contains no real content. It doesn't stand alone, isn't really searchable, and provides no *intrinsic* value. To be of any utility whatsoever, the user would have to follow the link rather than just reading the current page.

```
Read [Shell Globs for Fun and Profit][1].
```

#### See Also

[How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)