# What can I do to prevent the deletion of my answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I had some of my answers deleted without notification. Is this normal? There was no change in my reputation.

What can be done to prevent deletion?

Comment: *"What can be done to prevent deletion"*: Write good answers? `:o)` (I don't know your answers, but that normally works ;))

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: Your account looks extremely spammy. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980017/example-of-gif-certificate-functionality

Comment: Don't spam?  That usually helps.

Answer (score 15):

We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website. Per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion):

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details.

Any type of "astroturfing" promotion is not acceptable.  It brings down the overall value of genuine recommendations for everyone on the site.

If you can stay within the above guidelines, and offer questions and answers of genuine benefit to the community which happen to mention your affiliation or product in context -- and with full disclosure -- then your future contributions are welcome.

**See Also** 
[How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Comment: 9 votes for copy-pasting? Here, have a badge... _+1_

Comment: I fixed that for you.

Comment: Have any links of the deleted answers?  Or should you not post that?

Comment: @AdamRackis: If you have sufficient rep, you should be able to see them in the OP's account history.

Comment: Hmm - activity tab? Not showing up (and I'm 25K)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think we mortals have a way to see them in the profile of users. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Normal users (peasants, if you will) can't see deleted content in activity, although we can view the deleted content if of sufficient reputation and if given a link.

Comment: I'm reluctant to surface information that users can't normally see.  The OP is certainly welcome to provide those links, if he wishes.

Comment: No problem @robert - it's really a non-issue.  The deletions were most certainly valid - was just curious what he was spamming.

Answer (score 2):

If it so happens that an answer or post-as-a-whole does become deleted, yes it's usually done without notification, and so it's quite normal for you to be un-notified for a deletion.

As for how to prevent that from happening, it's best to be well-informed on community conduct and confident that you aren't committing any (unintentional) faux pas with your writing.  Generally speaking, if you think you might be out of line, proceed with caution, and *most* people are pretty good about guiding you in the right direction.

That said, there are a few bad apples around just about every web community, so be prepared to deal with the occasional jerk.  You can of course "flag" jerks too.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help! :)

Comment: What is sad that I can not even vote up yet :(