# Get back onto stackoverflow account

Tags: support, status-bydesign, post-ban

I thought I was answering or helping a PHP developer and got a post ban. Thx for fixing this.

Comment: Could you please include the actual code in your answers? What's up with all the pastie.org links?

Comment: the formatting gets all messed up the code blocks are huge

Comment: Hm? Code formatting seems to be working for everyone else, perhaps you should take a quick look at the [markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, [most of your code snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1816093+is%3Aanswer+pastie.org&submit=search) seem to be very small. 89 lines is the larger one I found, and that's hardly huge...

Comment: well sometimes there are 2 or three of these http://pastie.org/5364183

Comment: Yeap, I already saw that, it's not what I'd call huge. In any case it should fit nicely in your answer,.

Comment: the combined total of this would have been 285 lines. thought it was a benefit to readers not a hindrance   ....   http://pastie.org/5364605

Comment: Answers should be complete, you are not helping readers by asking them to go to another site to see the complete solution. And in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13340606/99456) you just went too far, your link doesn't lead to the solution, but three other links? How's that a benefit to readers?

Comment: they are developers they read

Comment: Even if they are developers, they really don't have time to traverse links. Link-only answers are discouraged and other users don't really post links like you do.

Comment: hey i've been here two days now i know

Comment: Now, to fix your post ban, I would edit code back into your answers, eliminate links, and otherwise streamline your answers to be upvote-attracting.

Comment: well that would be nice because i can't even comment just answer

Comment: well i can;t do anything on this system right now i am read only

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Answer (score 8):

You're not "read only". The only thing you're prevented from doing right now is posting more answers because the ones you've posted so far have been downvoted, deleted, or not voted on at all. This block is fully automated.

Among other things, we use votes as a measure of how much the community values and trusts your input. So to get your ability to post answers reinstated, you need to get the system to trust you again. You can do this by posting questions that attract upvotes, suggesting edits to improve others' posts, and/or editing our existing answers to improve them and get other users to upvote them.

Looking at your answers, I see that you primarily post short suggestions, sometimes with a barely described link. While you make improvements to get your access re-enabled, you should strongly consider reading the following:

- the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page
- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I also suggest paying close attention to spelling, punctuation, etc. All of that matters when someone is trying to read and learn from your answers.

Comment: so basically i can not contribute. my answers are actually long as they are in links to code snippets.

Comment: @DrewPierce Unfortunately, that doesn't count. All posts should be stand-alone even if all links break.

Comment: @DrewPierce You can start by editing the relevant and most useful parts of your snippets into your answers to make them self-contained.

Comment: but i cannot edit them

Comment: and u lost a great resource

Comment: @DrewPierce There should be an "edit" link below every one of your answers. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13352324/edit), for example. What happens when you click that?

Comment: nah i will come here to consume not feed like everyone else

Comment: That's a nice way to say thx for fixing this.

Comment: the thing that strike me most is that developers are just looking for  code that works. maybe not exactly the way they want it but they tweak it. so in two days i post 3 dozen answers or so and developers get it but mods don't. developers are on google they are here for a minute then follow the next link on page 1 of their search.

Comment: @DrewPierce While we do get a lot of "reader" traffic, many developers like you and (formerly) me are also using Stack Overflow and they tend to upvote answers they find helpful. People vote with their, well, votes around here.

Comment: they read, they tinker, they read, rinse and repeat. but the mods here thinks that a solution or Answer needs to solve it but it rarely does.  most are just flat out junk. then a mod comes along and  says That is not an answer. Well heck what do they know about nuance. They are mods. It is arbitrary and they are ignorant of it all. Like dumb cops on The Andy Griffen show. But guys like me are trying to craft an answer for some dumb schmuck out there for an hour and in you swoop.

Comment: It is pathetic. And then the Asker got his free question and swoops and never votes except for the disgruntled techie that just wants to crap on people because this whole thing blows and he does a down vote. what a great system

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not quite sure what you're talking about anymore. All we're trying to do here is to get your answer-posting access reinstated.

Comment: i dont have access all i can do is request indent changes

Comment: Never fear! Consuming and feeding on the toes is the same thing @dre

Comment: @DrewPierce That suggests to me something else's going on. You should be able to edit your existing answers and comment on them, just as before. This is a stupid question, but are you signed in?

Comment: ha press a button make it go away

Comment: and where is that going to get me points

Comment: they age and die on the vine

Comment: so i can't answer a question, i can't post a question

Comment: i can modify old edits that no one cares about

Comment: that is a great path to success. why, because i used pastie

Comment: @Drew, you're comporting yourself very poorly. Folks here are helping you, and you're insulting them. Take a day off, come back tomorrow, and try again.

Comment: Michael, help me understand how the folks are trying to help me. I produced some good stuff in 3 days. My stmts above are just stating the obvious. Get it for free segment of developers. But don't take it out on the ones that produce.

Comment: No one's taking it out on you. I understand how it might feel that way, but look at it from our point of view. We get crap. Piles and piles of crap. Day and night, crap questions mostly, but answers as well. The ban is a self-defense mechanism. It's not a perfect solution, but it's the best one we've come up with.

Comment: You can work yourself out from under the ban. The linked post tells you how. Tell you what - if you improve your answers as folks here have suggested, and as Unhandled's link and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) discuss, I'll vote the worthy ones up. That's how you escape the ban.

Comment: no M I do no deserve to be banned in any way let's be real so if you are the man just lift it

Comment: i have already proved myself now it is time for your team to suck it up or not move on in anyway together

Comment: Okey-dokey. You're rage-quitting. That's cool. Blessings on your life.

Comment: no rage here Michael. Nice try. I write code.

Comment: @DrewPierce Like I said, the ban is automated. There is no button or link or anything that will just lift it. I gave you the steps you can take. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Ah the passive-aggressive ending but what does one expect.

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.