# Create detailed "How-to-review" meta posts and link to them from the Review queues?

Tags: feature-request, review

I've seen all kinds of material on MSO about how to perform reviews correctly, what you should accept, and what you should reject, but I am quite surprised to find there is no link on the Review page itself pointing to this material.

Can we add a link to the Review pages that points to the relevant meta-faq posts on how to review items?

In my experience, most people want to do the "right" thing, although not many actually know what the "right" thing is, so it's our job to educate them.

I know it may seem like common knowledge to users familiar with the system, however I can tell you from personal experience that many SO users really have no idea there are rules and a meta community for the site, and that MSO contains all kinds of extra information. All they see is "oh hey some new item called Review is highlighted by my name, I should check it out and play with it"

**Edit:** I was almost positive I'd read some really good meta-faq posts about the review system, but I can't find them now so they're probably not tagged meta-faq or they were just some really good answers to one of the many meta questions about the new review system. The only thing I can find now is [this faq-proposed post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/158605), which still needs some work.

Comment: I recently created a community wiki post intended to be a central repository for review guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/review-guidelines. However, I'm not sure if that will fly.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks for the link, I've added it to my question. I thought for sure I had seen some meta-faq posts about Review already, but I can't find it so I must be mistaken.

Comment: The currents system is still too new, so there are a lot of discussions about it, but no faq/canonical answers yet. That's why I created those guidelines post, but unfortunately I couldn't write much. Feel free to contribute to it, please!