# What repercussions are there to "not paying attention" when reviewing?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I just clicked "Do nothing" instead of skipping what turned out to be a trick post or at least what the system deemed a poor answer. I was derided by some text telling me to pay attention. Yes, the answer should have been a comment, but I thought it was important enough to let the viewers of the question decide (which they turned out to already have by telling the poster to comment rather than answer)

Will I be flagged as a poor reviewer now, or was it just a "wake-up" call?

I take my reviewing very seriously so I would be devastated if this would tarnish my perceived capabilities...

**NOTE:** the offense was to do nothing to [this now deleted answer/comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823967/295783) to

["query end" step very long at random times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937443/query-end-step-very-long-at-random-times)

In this case, I should have skipped, but the tone of the comment was such I thought it better to let the visitors to the question decide rather than delete it. In the areas I am knowledgeable, I would extract the answer and post as a comment before rejecting it.

PS: I just received a badge, so I cannot even be suspected for badge hunting...

Comment: Mostly it is a wakeup call, however, the have started manually [banning some users for have failed multiple tests within a short time frame](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158675/182513).

Comment: As for how many hits you can get before suspended, Shog9 says in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158418/careless-review-upvotes-are-actively-contributing-to-the-quality-problem-not-co?lq=1#comment458383_158505): "At four failures, I start looking closely - four in a week, very closely" so I'd say you're still in a good standing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't ban for a single offense of course, but if you're not paying attention to what you're doing:

- Stop
- Take a break
- Come back later, *if you want*

The queues don't need to be emptied *right now* and there's plenty to do...content will always need updating and improving.  Don't get burnt out on the queues, they're meant to be helpful *and* enjoyable, the should *not* feel like a job.  When they do stop and do something else.

The queues need a proper review or they're not useful, and you're not as useful or happy as a zombie user, we don't want unhappy users.

Comment: Please see update for more information - I was actually paying attention in my opinion...

Answer (score 3):

That counts as a strike against you towards a [review suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158505/200500). I'm not certain exactly how many chances you get (bans are manual), but there are no immediate effects unless you fail several, so I wouldn't worry about it.

If you aren't certain what action to take in a review situation, click the skip button. "No action" is for when there is nothing wrong with the answer. It is difficult to say more without seeing the review in question, but honeypot answers usually have glaring flaws that you can pick up on.

Regarding your update, the reason the answer was a comment is because it cannot stand on its own. If the other answer were to be deleted, the remark:

> Setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 isn't a solution to adopt
>   lightly, it fundamentally changes the durability of your transactions!

would make no sense. This is a meta-answer, in that it addresses another answer instead of the original question. Regardless of whether the point it raises is valid, this "answer" is therefore a comment.

I do agree that this one is a bit tough to call, which is why you can press skip whenever you feel undecided, particularly when you don't have enough knowledge in the subject area.

Comment: Yes, I often hit skip, especially when I am in areas I am not an expert in. In this particular case, the tone of the answer/comment was such that I decided to do nothing instead of skipping...

Comment: @mplungjan I've added an update. I wonder what the correct course of action would have been if the comment by NeilMonday were not present. There was no other way for you to have realised the answer was a reply to a different answer.

Comment: Sure - I would have pressed skip. Since I could not see that the comment was to an answer, I decided that it might be important. I agree that it should be a comment, I was not sure it would disappear if I skipped it, so I decided to instead click "do nothing" I will of course never make that mistake again if someone decides my course of action is tantamount to not paying attention when in this case I was paying too much attention.