# Close vote review audit flawed - fails without casting vote

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Having just [failed my first review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2085329) from any of the queues, it was reviewing close votes; however, this audit was flawed in that I didn't even cast a close vote.

Often I press the *Close* button to preview greater detail and sentiment of the closure, spawning the *Why should this question be closed* dialog box:

[image: why-should-this-be-closed]

Especially for duplicates, where functionality is solely dependent on spawning this dialog.

From *Closing > Duplicate*, I can search or view selected duplicates:

[image: duplicates]

Although, I realize general closure reasons are summarized on the page:

[image: summary]

This question had 6-upvotes, but seemed very localized referencing subjective query is "taking too long" and even had a sqlfiddle link.  Maybe overly broad regarding performance tuning, the OP was posting like a forum with two answer posts to his own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15978448/798448) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961025/798448) with one of those answers asking follow-up questions.

Wanting to gauge community response, current closure totals struck my curiosity.

So, I pressed the *Close* button and boom - oh, the humanity!  I failed, and didn't even cast a close vote.

Votes are not cast until a reason for closure is selected and *Vote to Close* is pressed.

Taking any review very seriously on this site, it only seems fair that my review quality is tested through actionable steps instead of clicking for more detailed information, leveraging the functional design of the close vote user interface.

Sure, it's complex to seed fake vote totals, and then there's controversy of mindless voting in the majority or people who simply cherry pick 4-vote questions.

Still though, it seems unfair I should hesitate to review further information of vote totals and duplicates before skipping due to the implementation of this audit.

Comment: If you aren't supposed to use this information to help you decide whether to vote to close it shouldn't be displayed at all.

Comment: I think there should be some sort of *Or do you genuinely believe this should be closed?* dialog to redeem yourself when failing close audits. I'm pretty sure the questions which are pulled are done at random, and there are always going to be a few which have slipped through the net which should be closed but aren't.

Comment: Erm, wait, you pressed the Close button and didn't expect the system to think that you wanted to close the question?  If you don't know the close reasons well enough to need the selection page then how could you possibly review accurately?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: There is no need of *"Do you genuinely believe this should be closed?"* dialog. There is already a button called **Vote to Close**.. Review Audit should consider if we pressed this button for Closure..

Comment: @UphillLuge No, I want vote totals / duplicates functionality of the _Why should this question be closed_.  Casting a vote occurs on _Vote to close_, not pressing the _Close_ button.  After 1,477 close vote reviews, I'm pretty familiar with closure options.

Comment: @UphillLuge I've voted to close 835 questions and even now I'll open up the close menu on a question I'm either probably not going to close, or am only debating closing, just to re-read the specific wordings.  Honestly that page has the most helpful information to consider as to whether or not a question should be closed.  Do I need to check it every time, no of course, not, but I'll look at every now and again to refresh my memory, pull an exact quote from the description to post in a comment, or just to think over a borderline case.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit

Comment: @EsotericScreenName How is that related?

Comment: @JasonSturges It's discussing the same functionality: audit decisions being made as soon as you click flag or close.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Fair enough, minor overlap loosely coupled per _Wouldn't it be better to force the person to confirm the flag or deletion recommendation before displaying the audit results_.

Comment: Yes, the UI is pretty inconsistent here - [you beat me to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179768/184183) by half a day!

Comment: I've been running into this lately. I decided I'm just gonna fail every audit in this style, because I'm too used to clicking "Close" to see what people have done.

Comment: When a legitimate question is voted to be closed, my first reaction is to click the "Close" button to see what the heck. I guess I'm doomed to be banned. :(

Comment: I clicked on the close button to see how people were justifying closing the question, because I couldn't understand why it was closed. And then I saw, it wasn't...

Comment: This is off-topic because it would be better discussed on UX Stackexchange. :) Yeah, this bit me too.

Comment: the close and flag dialog are now fully functional in audits, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231658/156631

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> However, it kinda falls apart when you want to close a known-good
>   question as a duplicate.
>
> Fixing this would require dragging in code that's currently being
>   extensively re-written; doing so is not feasible at this time. It may
>   or may not become possible in the future - even without the current
>   re-write, the logic for that UI isn't trivial to fake.

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying a lot, but wouldn't it be kind of practical to just move the pass fail check to when the actual close vote is cast?

I'm thinking it could and likely should work in much the same way that suggested edit review audits currently work, with a caveat for duplicates.

1. Present the user with an audit
2. If the user clicks the close button, show the dialog as usual
3. If the user closes as a duplicate, behave as if it were a normal close vote
4. If the user chooses another close reason and clicks "vote to close" then pass/fail the audit appropriately

Like I said this is likely oversimplifying things by leaps and bounds, but I think this is the expected behavior.

If the concern is generating "fake" close votes so that the audit seems to show that other users voted to close the post for some reason or other... I'm not sure its entirely necessary.
I routinely see close vote reviews that don't have any indication of how many close votes the post has. I assume these are posts that have flags rather close votes, I would guess that most users are accustomed to seeing these reviews and wouldn't really think twice about not seeing the blue numbers.

Comment: I just got caught by this, do you know of any updates on plans to change this behavior ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer From the look of [shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770/217863) I don't think they've got any thing in the works yet, but it looks like momentum may be growing on this issue. It'll probably be 6-8 weeks...

Comment: @apaul34208 Any update yet?

Comment: @ZachSaucier http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/217863

Comment: Looks like when they fixed it, they didn't implement point 3.

Answer (score 43):

My usual flow when reviewing is:

1. Read the title
2. Read the question
3. Click the "Close" button, skim trough the reasons if I am not sure and verify that what I just read is okay with all the points.
4. Either click "X" to close the closing window and Leave Open or Skip, or choose the close reason and close.

**To clarify**; I am not interested in what other closevoters chose. I want to reread reason descriptions and use the searching for duplicates function (which also makes sense if I don't know if the question is a duplicate, I guess).

The obvious problem with that is that the test system slaps me automatically when I click "Close" to show the reasons, *when I haven't even made my decision*! Frankly, it's a bit annoying, because I often open the close reasons just to close them and leave the question open (so my decision isn't really done hastily), but I can't do that if the system punishes me for my method of reviewing.

In my opinion the test should be concluded only if one of the definitive outcomes is choses, that is one of close reasons, "leave open" or the user goes in edit mode. It should be changed if only for consistency with actual closevote casting process.

Answer (score -25):

I consider this behavior appropriate for *most* of the audits. If you're clicking "close", you probably do want to close the question.

However, it kinda falls apart when you want to close a known-good question [as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179768/is-the-ui-inconsistent-when-doing-a-audit-during-close-vote-reviewing).

**Update:** This should now be fixed, insofar as you'll have to actually *select* a close reason and click Vote before passing / failing the audit.

Comment: This audit needs reevaluated - testing press of _Close_ barely improves reviewers.  4-votes of a duplicate that's totally off, completely wrong closure reason, or even just blank with nothing selected would verify reviewer quality.  Logic for all audits isn't trivial, I'm sure.  Good time for fresh ideas if it's being reworked.  In general, I really like review audits - great solution to many problems.  Agreed at a high level, but close review audits could be improved.

Comment: I just got bitten by intention-to-close-as-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2321254

Comment: in current form, this answer looks like rather poor justification for audit test design. Particularly, an assumption that clicking _Close_ is a reliable indication of a desire to close, is wrong, as explained in a [duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192395/165773). If you believe that desire to see CV split or desire to do this from review queue justified audit failure, consider [edit]ing the answer to reflect that

Comment: ...as an example, reasoning in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192446/165773) shows a possible explanation for the audit preference: "I think it works better to read the question, evaluate it on its own merits, and decide..."

Comment: Yeah... I don't mind discouraging people from using others' votes as a justification for closing either, @gnat. The duplicate scenario is seriously annoying, since there's a legit reason to close that can't be guessed at by the audit-selector - but if you have to click "close" before you know whether or not a question should be closed, you've already failed.

Comment: @Shog9 the more I think about it, the more it looks like it is worth investing effort into coding tests that fail at the moment of [unambiguously proven failure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156942/165773 "as discussed here"). It is a honorable goal to teach people subtle intricacies of moderation, but so far it looks like getting audits there does more harm than good. The very dupe-closures wouldn't be an issue if audit would fail only at voting for the guaranteed wrong reason (that way, you'd have _usability_ complaints anyway but these would be of much lesser severity)

Comment: I completely agree that the audit system should not presume what you want to do before you do it. No sane audit system should do this. A vote to close is not cast until the "vote to close" button is clicked. An audit is designed to see if you "voted to close" a question. If you have not "voted to close" then the audit should not fail (presuming it is a question that should not be closed). I don't see how a counter-argument to that is even possible. An audit should audit what you do, not what it guesses you might want to do.

Comment: If it's not possible to build a functional auditing system from the existing UI logic then it shouldn't even be there to being with. There's no point in an auditing system that doesn't audit what you actually do.

Comment: We're still waiting.

Comment: This answer looks like an attempt to explain to the boss why a bad coding decision was made.

Comment: Failed a 'duplicate' review today because I wanted to check if something is a dupe of anything interesting. This is really annoying.

Comment: still being rewritten, I guess?

Comment: I often click the close button to reread reasons to validate. And I will definitely click it when I feel a question **SHOULDN'T** be closed to see what the hell people are talking about. I feel like this is important context.

Comment: @Willem: click "(more)" instead...

Comment: "If you're clicking 'close', you probably do want to close the question." I think I might not be the only one who uses the close dialog as a checklist. I open it *especially* when I think the question might need to be left open to double check that the question doesn't fall into a category where it should be closed. Also, sometimes there's text on "off-topic: other" which is important when considering whether or not to close a question.

Comment: As I told Willem, you can get an overview of the close reasons selected by clicking the "(more)" link, @zzzzBov. As a side bonus, this will stick open for your session then, speeding up this step for the next review.

Comment: @Shog9 Clicking "(more)" does not provide me with the same context information then when clicking close. I think the OP's post gives enough information on why that is.   
If you are genuinely afraid that people are just gonna cherry pick the most voted item then that's where audits might actually be useful. But 'clicking close' does **not** equal 'closing', surely you can see that right ?

Comment: :shrug: I'm telling you how to get the necessary information without inadvertently failing anything - if you don't want to use it, that's your call.

Comment: @Shog9, I get that. I think everyone everyone who gets bitten by the system and passed here knows how to prevent it. It is possible, but that's not what this thread is about. This is about pointing out a very obvious **usability** issue in the review workflow and hoping to get some feedback on it. Just saying "don't do it" is not helpful at all. You are a Community manager, so, tell the community; why is it that you can't even recognize this issue ? We're listening, thank you for your time.

Comment: My reasoning is stated in the answer here, @Willem. I use review on a regular basis and make no effort to recognize or avoid audits - the *only* time this trips me up is when I think the question I'm reviewing is a duplicate. Why do I not struggle with this UI? Because I don't click "Close" *unless I think the question should be closed*. If you're sitting there staring at a perfectly good question trying to think up a reason for it to be shut down, *you're doing it wrong* - so just stop doing that and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Shog9, "If you're sitting there staring at a perfectly good question trying to think up a reason for it to be shut down, *you're doing it wrong*" Questions don't typically end up in the queue accidentally, but before I can say that it shouldn't be closed I need to verify that it *doesn't* match one of the available close vote reasons (including the entire off-topic subgroup). This means that there are 11 different reasons that the question could be closed, and it must *not* fit into any of them before I can confidently click "leave open".

Comment: @Shog9, I open the close window because it acts as a checklist. Do you expect everyone to remember all the close reasons all the time? The simple solution for me is to just stop trying to help on the review queue. It sucks, but it beats being punished for trying to do the right thing. It's not my job to change my habits in reviewing questions.

Comment: I've never been bitten by this, but that's probably luck, or guessing when it is a likely audit test and just doing the expected. Especially since the close reasons quite recently changed, I find myself reviewing them and still voting "leave open".

Comment: You're over-thinking this, @zzzzBov. Step #1: is this question problematic? If the answer is "no", then you can skip that 11-point checklist.

Comment: @Shog9, there's a lot of grey area, I use the checklist so that I can try to be somewhat consistent, and to double check that I'm not forgetting a reason (off-topic to migrate to SU or SF are common cases where there's no problem with the question per-se, it would just fit better there).

Comment: You don't need to migrate things unless they're actually *off-topic* - wholly inappropriate - for Stack Overflow, @zzzz. Because of numerous complaints from SU and SF over the years, there's a really good chance your vote will end up NOT migrating the question unless this is actually the case.

Comment: @Shog9 can't the same interface that has the suggested edits honey pot be implemented for this? IMO it should be easy since there's something that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Shog9 can you elaborate on your update?  Does this mean if you select "duplicate" on an audit, it won't trigger a failure?

Comment: consider updating [your other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191930/165773) to clarify that the issue is fixed: _'Duplicate scenarios, unfortunately, have the potential to break a lot of our "known good" audits...'_

Comment: note fake failures are fixed for voting to close but seem to remain broken when [flagging to close as dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271239/review-audit-making-obvious-failure-on-duplicate-flag "bug report")

Comment: @Shog9: [This meta post on Meta.Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17182/duplicates-as-review-audits) seems to hint at something similar. Can someone look at it?