# Bad audit question for close votes

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just got the close vote privilege on SO today. I received this question as an audit. I voted to close it (could be flagged as "too broad" or "more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com"), and apparently that was not the correct choice:

[image: Screen Shot]

This question would never fly here.

1. Why did that happen? Should I expect more poor audit questions?
2. Is there any consequence of failing these?

Comment: not too broad IMO. Wouldn't close. As for the audit selection criteria and the consequences, these are already documented on meta.

Comment: At the very least "opinion based". His own reasoning even starts with "in my opinion...".

Comment: Are you a robot, or a human? If you're a human: does this question ask for opinions, or facts? I'd say, it asks for facts (even if the asker has his own opinion)

Comment: Are you asking me if "are you a robot or a human" asks for an opinion or... what? Can I vote to close a comment as "unclear what you are asking"?

Comment: I am asking you two questions. The first question is "are you a robot or a human?". The second question is "[in your opinion,] does this question ask for opinions, or facts?". The first question is asked unconditionally. The second question is asked iff the response to the first question is "I'm a human". The next sentence is my response to the second question (presence of which does not imply that I don't expect your answer to the second question).

Comment: and no, you cannot close (or close vote) a comment.

Comment: I guess I don't follow. Whether I'm a robot or a human is not a matter of opinion. Those are two well defined concepts and there are concrete criteria that determine which one I am. Unless I'm a Cylon, I guess.

Comment: @JanDvorak "and no, you cannot close (or close vote) a comment." Is that an opinion or a fact? Are you a robot? :P

Comment: I've also been seeing more and more of these low-quality audits

Comment: I never claimed that you being a robot is a matter of opinion. Why do you think I did? Note that "this question" in my second question refers to the question of which the audit was concerned, not to the first question. It would be weird if I asked you "In your opinion, does "Are you a robot, or a human?" ask for opinions, or facts?" I am not asking that. Also note that "Are you a robot, or a human?" was primarily meant as a rhetorical question. Now, I am not so sure, so please answer this objective answer in accordance with the objective truth: Are you a robot, or a human?

Comment: We're all unicorns. Either that or waffle-irons.

Comment: @JanDvorak I will answer it under one condition: Does my answer to your question affect my opinion on the audit I posted above? If not then I have to move on now and leave some room for other discussion.

Comment: I don't agree with "opinion-based". Although the OP declared his own opinion, there can be factual reasons for "why such as such is bad practice". As for "too broad", it doesn't seem to be those kind of questions that would need an extremely long answer. Partly because it's asking about a specific function and a specific option. So yeah, I don't think it should be closed. That being said, I don't know JS so I might be wrong about this.

Comment: Then "minimal knowledge". Or whatever. It falls into almost half the flagging categories. If you cannot show your code, describe your problem, outline what you've tried and how your actual results differ from your expected, then it simply doesn't belong on SO. That doesn't mean it's a bad question. In fact I think the audit question is a very interesting one... for a different site that isn't SO. See the SO FAQ. See the ubiquitous http://sscce.org/. This question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: Or if it makes you happy, I'd just flag it as more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: you don't migrate a question just because it's on-topic on some other site. You migrate a question because it's a high quality question that is offtopic where it was asked, and that should be asked somewhere else. Also, you don't migrate old questions.

Comment: @JanDvorak July 22 isn't that old is it? It's not even a Aug 22 yet...

Comment: @JanDvorak I completely agree with that policy on migration. And so, I'd just flag it as more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Sorry, I thought I mentioned that.

Comment: In my opinion, positive audits should be slam dunk questions, using borderline questions leaves too much room for interpretation. Best practice or bad practice questions nearly always raise debate at some level, so using one for an audit seems like a poor choice.

Comment: @apaul34208 The other problem with audits on borderline questions is the actual action taken relies on 5 people coming to the same conclusion. If one person comes to an "incorrect" conclusion on a borderline question, the audit fails, but in reality the question may not have been closed. So the reality is, for borderline questions, the auditing system isn't auditing whether you're paying attention or not, it's auditing whether or not your view on the question conforms to a majority view. I have a feeling that's *not* the real goal of the system. So something is broken there.

Comment: audits don't work that way, they don't rely on any response other than your own.

Comment: I know. That's precisely my point. For a borderline question you fail your audit if you don't vote the way the system essentially assumes 4 other people *would* vote. Therefore when these kinds of borderline questions come up, the system conceptually breaks. Since the audit's *designed* goal is to make sure you're *paying attention*, the questions it gives should *all* be slam dunks one way or the other, just like the suggested edit audits.

Comment: That being said I understand where you're coming from. "Good" audit questions seem to be chosen based on up-votes and views, which don't always mean it would make for a great audit question

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question. Yes, [you could contort some of the close reasons so that they apply to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192445/i-failed-an-audit-and-want-some-clarification/192446#192446), but I don't think you should. It is not the unanswerable type of opinion-based question. Like several commenters have pointed out, it is really asking for facts. I rather like that audits are catching those who tend to vote to close based on keywords or cursory evaluations of questions, rather than a thorough attempt to understand and evaluate its appropriateness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your three basic questions:

> Why did this happen?

You voted to close a question that the system judged to be a good question.

> Should I expect more poor audit questions?

Most likely yes, if by poor audit questions you mean audits that you're likely to disagree with.

> Is there any consequence of failing these?

Yes, if you fail several in short period you will be temporarily booted from the close vote review. If you're paying attention this wont likely be a problem, most audits aren't that bad from what I've seen.

See [Tim Post's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189009/217863) for more info on how audit questions are chosen and so on.