# Clicking "Improve" causes fail of audit

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I know this was asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169580/improve-treated-as-improper-response-to-proper-response-to-audit), but nothing was ever changed in the system. Why should I be locked out from reviews for a week for trying to improve something? Although I know in [my failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2773481) that the edit was not salvageable, some original posts need editing, which I would do, unchecking the "helpful" box.

When you are presented with an edited post audit and you click "Reject," you must give a reason before you pass/fail. Why should this be any different?

Comment: More or less the same case as this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194110/rights-for-reviewing-revoked-while-improving-post

Comment: In a situation like this, but when the original post requires improvement, I would roll it back first, and edit that.

Comment: Why? Just reject, or skip. These are obvious audit.

Comment: Why would it be better protocol to click the title to go to the post page and edit it there, instead of clicking "Improve," rolling it back, and unchecking the "Useful" box?

Comment: @Mooseman are you asking why you can't make real edits to the original post from inside the audit?  Or are you asking why should trying to edit cause you to fail since you can undo the edit from the queue?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The second one. Is there a reason I should go back to the post page to fix it other than not failing the audit? The audit should fail if you attempt to submit an edit without rolling back the post and/or leaving the "Useful" box checked.