# count "helpful flags" in review audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, helpful-flags

When passing a review audit, the number of review tasks completed is increased, even though the audit is not a real review task.

My question:
If I passed the audit by flagging the post (for example, flagging a new post as low quality), why shouldn't my "helpful flags" counter be incremented as well?
Shouldn't this flag be counted just as the review task is counted?

Thanks

Comment: If I'm right it isnt even possible to flag an audit for something because if you press the flag link you have already passed the audit.

Comment: Which review audit? You're not able to flag during edit/CTV reviews.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I believe this is relevant mainly to "first posts"

Comment: let's not worry about whether you can or cannot flag. @Shai is just greedy and wants extra flag count to get badges :P

Comment: @ronalchn - you see right through me... can I flag my own question? ;-)

Comment: Shai the same applies to "Late Answers" and I agree with you that this should be counted as increase in flag count too. (+1)

Comment: Would propose to change the question to something like «Increase Flag count OR remove the Flag process in First Post and Late Answers». By removing the flag process I mean to make it work like in any other review type that clicking to flag automatically makes us pass the audits. One of the counter arguments for not going with it could be to teach people which flag types are out there (simply by stating an advantage of seeing that) but one doesn't need to keep being reminded it (if one wills, give the option to not see that and we'll see what prevails).

Answer (score 8):

You can't flag the post given for review-audit.

If you click the flag button, then the system will show you the message

[image]

So, the flag count will not be incremented as you didn't flagged it(even after flagging one can get increment in flag count when that flag was found helpful by any moderators/ 10k + users).

Comment: well, the fact that it is technically difficult to implement does not change my argument: should or should not these flags be counted. How to do it - it's an alltogether another question...

Comment: @Shai: you didn't flag anything when you click on flag on a review edit. Why should that count as a valid flag? You don't even get to choose a flag reason.

Comment: Is it also true that clicking the flag, on an audit where flagging is not appropriate, is enough to fail an audit? e.g. browsing reasons why it might be flaggable...

Comment: @Azik this answer isn't true if you're reviewing "First Posts" or "Late Answers". (-1)

Comment: @Mat that's not true. You go through a normal flag process when reviewing "First Post" or "Late Answers".

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 No, Mat was right. At the time of this answer, you only had to click flag or recommend deletion. The process where you actually had to 'submit' a flag through the flag dialog was only implemented in 2014: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231658/369802.

Comment: Thank you for that information @Tinkeringbell