# Why do review audits consume our daily quota of flags?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

To help kill some time this evening I decided to go down the [/review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and help raise some flags until I'd used up my daily allowance. After doing so I proceeded to do a few review audits, however I'm now faced with two problems:

1. I can't flag audit posts which require flagging.
2. I can't pass test audits which require a flag to be assigned.

For each of these situations I'm forced to Skip the review completely, making it a much lengthier process to reach the review cap (especially for First Posts and Late Answers).

Why do review audits consume our daily quota of flags? Would it not be better to always allow users to flag content which appears within audits regardless of their remaining flags?

Furthermore, when assigning test audits, shouldn't the system detect whether the user is able to flag (or close, for that matter) prior to displaying a test which requires such an action?

Comment: 1+ I came across the same thing yesterday. On **some** of them, though, you can simply downvote and that will allow you to pass.. but still, you should be allowed to flag it either way... Same goes for the low quality posts that require a close vote -- If you don't have any allotted close votes left, you are unable to review those.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your terminology here; review *audits* don't count toward your *flag* quota. Obviously if you flag a post *from* review (only possible if you're *not* being shown an audit), that will count.

Comment: @Shog9 He means, if you have otherwise used all your flags you are unable to flag such audits as you no longer have any flags to use.

Comment: Ah. I... hadn't thought to test that.

Comment: I thought just clicking on the flag link on a known-bad audit instantly passed the audit? Does it matter if you have no flags left?

Comment: @animuson hmm you may be right, actually. I've just been skipping anyway as there isn't much point in me opening the flag post UI.

Comment: @animuson The issue still exists though, whether it be an audit or not. You should still be able to flag non-audit reviews if you don't have any flags left. In the event that it's not an audit, you actually need to load the flag UI, and take appropriate actions.

Comment: @JoshC I disagree - the whole point of a flag limit is to globally limit your ability to flag. This shouldn't just be removed because it is convenient in a review scenario. If you think it is an audit, you can try to flag and see what happens.

Comment: @DuncanJones I'm not proposing a removal of the flag limit outside of reviews, rather reviews that require a flag for further actions should be allowed regardless of whether you have flags left or not. I am not merely talking about audits, as I said in my last comment. Therefore simply clicking flag isn't enough assuming it's not an audit. In the event that it actually isn't an audit you need to actually be able to flag it. That being said, if you no longer have any flags, you are rendered unable to review any further. That is an issue.

Comment: @JoshC I still disagree - I think a flag limit should apply globally and in every circumstance. If you encounter questions in the review queue that require flagging, you could always skip them if you are out of flags. I don't see the review queue requiring different rules to the rest of the site. However, we are going off on a tangent here so I'll refrain from further replies.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, review audits should not look different from actual reviews, so users who try to use the [flag loophole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit) can't use it anymore. You have to actually submit the flag for the review result to be displayed, which still requires you to have at least one flag left.

Comment: The flag loophole would be closed these days anyway simply because of the presence of positive audits.