# Can't flag or close questions on all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, javascript

Whenever I try to flag or close a question here, when clicking the submit button the button gets disabled, three dots animating and nothing really happens.

JS console show a single error:

Flagging:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'flagSubmitting' of undefined

Closing:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closeSubmitting' of undefined

Please fix, programming questions and spam are beginning to pile up. :(

**Update: appears to work fine from within the review system, but otherwise it's the same on Stack Overflow as well**

Comment: I thought it was just my connection.

Comment: @Flexo nope. When in doubt, check the Console. :-)

Comment: I'm also seeing this on Stack Exchange, although the console error is "TypeError: C is undefined".

Comment: @ShadowWizard I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'flagSubmitting' of undefined " on SO. Try flagging http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667897/1402846

Comment: @Pang yeah, I tried from the close review where it does still work.

Comment: Came here just to report this, but looks like you beat me too it

Comment: @psubsee2003 well actually credit goes to Mystical who was [the first to notice and report](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2046967#2046967), otherwise I would have missed it until trying to flag or close. :)

Comment: I've tried on SO and MSO as well, and had the same problem.

Comment: Fix is being pushed for this right now.

Comment: Did anyone spin the wheel of blame?

Comment: @TimPost as a moderator, perhaps you can close [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671876/even-tho-this-fruit-has-been-around-for-thousands) immediately?

Comment: @ImmerAllein Mods go through the same system except that their votes are binding. So if we can't flag it, they can't either. A push by a dev is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [a bit of plumbing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit) going on ...

[image]

Well, *this* might be a more accurate depiction:

[image]

A fix <strike>is being</strike> has been deployed.

Comment: Is this the punishment for the responsible dev? Looks cruel, even in your standards! :-D

Comment: I always wonder, where do you get all those relevant images from?

Comment: @DroidDev I've got probably thousands of images of things that are 'overly complicated' - many of them with plumbing / cabling depicted because that's one of the most common software engineering analogies. I've just been collecting them for years. And, I'm a big Stooges fan.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Could be worse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teufz17PqoY)

Comment: @TimPost - I did a bit more digging in and found out that there was another bug appearing on the load of every page. [I happened to mention it in my post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231655/216721). Just wanted to know if this bug is being fixed too? Or is that something totally unrelated to this? Btw, Curly was my favorite among them :)

Comment: @DroidDev I suspect he's stealing images from Bart, he also seems to have endless repository. ;)

Comment: If you have ever seen [ben 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10) you should be knowing, plumbers used to save world from aliens. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case, bart can sue him for using his images for rep harvesting. ;) :)

Comment: If someone actually tried to sue me for rep I'd probably start throwing my badges at them, _with the pins open_.

Comment: I thought mods could call unicorns in these kind of fights. ^)

Comment: @DroidDev Huh? Mods _are_ unicorns in these kinds of fights.