# Bug in close vote review audit - can't close a known bad

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

So I was doing some reviews and got this one.  I clicked the 'close' button and was shown this:

[image: After clicking the 'close' button]

Note that its May 16th, not April 30th and its a review based on [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237458/help-me-please-with-this-question-and-problem)

I was more expecting to see the happy review message rather than the close screen.

Closing the panel and reopening it (with the close button) doesn't complete the review, but instead shows me a variation on the question with different numbers in red.  Note also the "Should this be closed as: ?" text rather than some close reason.

I eventually clicked 'leave open' so that I could complete there review and get a link to it so that if there *is* a bug here, it has something that can be hunted down (rather than "I clicked skip").  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/62812

So, somewhere in there, I suspect there's a bug.

Comment: I'm also getting the empty close reason on SO: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4EVGX.png

Comment: I guess we'll have to teach the close dialog a thing or two about review audits then. Caused by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit/231658#231658).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both issues will be fixed with build rev `2014.5.19.2255` on meta and `2014.5.19.1612` on sites.

Comment: Though, now the "known bad" close audit reviews show up as "this question has already been closed - please refresh the page" and don't show up in the history of the review queue. I haven't tried failing one yet to see what that does.

Comment: @MichaelT That has nothing to do with the close dialog. Will verify anyway though.

Comment: Is this change out yet on P.SE?  If so, its still reproducible (this is from an audit): http://i.stack.imgur.com/9oIBk.png ... for that matter, *all* (ok, not all, just most(?)) of my close reviews are saying that I've already voted on them (and I haven't)