# Do I benefit from Stack Exchange badges/scores?

Tags: discussion, review, badges

https://stackoverflow.com/review says

> there are no review queues available to you because one of my reviews wasn't helpful...Come back on Sep 3 at 6:41 to continue reviewing.

OK. 
So the question that arises immediately is "What is in it for me?"

Am I going to get paid or something or are there other benefits in trying my best to help this site?

The way Stack Exchange application talks to me says there are benefits in being active and nice and diligent on these sites.

I'm just curious about this. Maybe there is something I'm not aware of. What's the point behind these badges, scores...?

Comment: I've always felt the best excuse for doing edits and reviews is "It bothers me"

Comment: What is the gist? A complaint about the (indirect) rate limiting related to getting some badges? Or something else? (indirect = paying attention ([not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203102/implement-some-mechanism-to-avoid-robo-approvers) [robo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits?r=SearchResults&s=1|165.1116) [reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228737/does-robo-reviewing-stop-after-failed-audits?r=SearchResults&s=3|86.0520)))

Comment: Apparently, you are banned from reviewing for more than 4 months. How many suspensions happened before that?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/review really say *"...because one of my reviews..."*? Not *"...because one of* ***your*** *reviews..."* (my emphasis)?

Comment: [500 reputation points give access to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292) review queues *"First Posts"*, *"Late Answers"*, and *["Triage"](https://stackoverflow.com/review)*. 2000 reputation points give access to review queues *"Suggested Edits"*, *"Low Quality Posts"*, and *"Help and Improvement"*. 3000 reputation points give access to review queues *"Close Votes"* and *"Reopen Votes"*. (***See the footnotes***).

Comment: So this could be a case of *[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)*.

Comment: What review queue, Vahid2015, is it? Triage?

Comment: Your review on triage/25962116 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing" option should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better shape...

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[4 month review ban for just one incorrect review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397052)* - e.g. *["The long ban period is to ensure you actually see the message, rather than it expiring on its own before you decide to visit review again. If you want to be unbanned, the usual thing to do is to make sure you read the various posts on how "Requires Editing" should (or shouldn't) be used and show that you understand it now"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397052/4-month-review-ban-for-just-one-incorrect-review#comment767863_397052)*.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek . . . I tend to agree with you. So that would mean, that you do not look at those Review Queues at all? Today, I have finished doing some reviews on StackOverflow's Review Queues for the first time, but it does not seem to be beneficial for me at all. I do not seem to get reputation points for helpful reviews, for example. So it might even be the case, that performing such reviews could actually be harmful for my reputation if I would make mistakes? If that is the case, I will avoid such risks and stop actively reviewing anything in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one privilege I am aware that's bound to a gold badge for a particular tag: The so called *dupe hammer*.
It allows you to close questions tagged with that same tag as a duplicate single handedly.

Comment: The OP's real question may or may not be *"Why am I banned from reviewing for 4 months? I just want to get a badge!"* That is, *"The system encourages certain activities by means of badges (and "scores"), but now the same system prevents that. Why? I just want to help!"*

Comment: It [seems to be the *"Triage"* queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347264/do-i-benefit-from-stack-exchange-badges-scores#comment1162418_347264), thus likely a case of *[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)*. This is strengthened by the length of the review ban - *[4 month review ban for just one incorrect review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397052)*

Answer (score 6):

What's in it for you?

## Continued access to a curated collection of quality Q&A

Leaving aside the decaying allure of reputation and badge rewards over time, the site's chief "compensation" is simply the utility it provides to your home and professional life. That utility is largely contingent upon the quality of our Q&A. In order to maintain that quality, the site relies on people to curate content through voting, reviewing, and editing. Without that work, you'd see a precipitous degradation of quality, impacting your ability to find helpful information.

So, the question is really this: do you find the site useful enough (or trust enough in its potential) that you're personally motivated to protect its integrity?

If not, that's okay; nothing's really *required* of you. Certainly, much of curation (particularly the review queues) is thankless custodial work. Still, it's important for the site's health. So, if you're inclined to help, don't get discouraged when acting in good faith. Just try to understand what the system is telling you with its feedback. Make adjustments to your approach. Make use of the help resources. Bring specific problem cases to meta when necessary.

Don't let this stuff frustrate you. We're always appreciative of the work people do to make this site better.

Comment: The OP's real question may or may not be *"Why am I banned from reviewing for 4 months? I just want to get a badge!"* That is, *"The system encourages certain activities by means of badges (and "scores"), but now the same system prevents that. Why? I just want to help!"*

Comment: It [seems to be the *"Triage"* queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347264/do-i-benefit-from-stack-exchange-badges-scores#comment1162418_347264), thus likely a case of *[Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394498/triage-needs-to-be-fixed-urgently-and-users-need-to-be-notified-upon-receiving)*. This is strengthened by the length of the review ban - *[4 month review ban for just one incorrect review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397052)*