# Is there a way to present better criteria for closing a question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I recently started doing more reviews on Stack Overflow and found that a lot of times the description for the closing reasons was not really helpful at all. I takes some wading and searching through Meta to find for example that basically the "Here is some code that isn't working please fix it" is considered "Too localized". Or am I wrong with this one?

I think it would be helpful for the users *and* the reviewers to have a list of questions as samples for each of the categories that have been closed for specific reasons.

The three to four line description does not seem very helpful in a lot of cases, even links to discussions here would be a boon to new reviewers.

[EDIT]

So possible solutions:

- [Add a link to the more detailed “How-to-review” Meta posts in Review pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155770/add-a-link-to-the-more-detailed-how-to-review-meta-posts-in-review-pages)
- Add more text to the review interface guidelines, or the faq
- Add links to a canonical set of closed questions as examples for each category
- Add a tag to meta that users can use to find all concrete discussions on closing questions to separate it from the process tag 'vote-to-close' I suggest 'vote-to-close-example', for example on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161084/are-questions-that-are-solely-unique-to-the-programming-profession-on-topic)

Any other solutions?

Comment: +1 I agree the Review Queue could definitely use some links to more detailed instructions. In fact, I even posted a related meta post about it: [Add a link to the more detailed “How-to-review” meta posts in Review pages?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155770/158605)

Comment: +1 It takes guts to suggest that SO isn't perfect.

Comment: I believe better/more descriptive close reasons are a work in progress. I can't seem to find the specific post where this was mentioned, but it might address some of your concerns. If I find it again I'll link to it.