# Incorrect comment count in inbox

Tags: bug, comments

I seem to have a consistent incorrect count between the number of comments shown in my inbox 4

[image: snapshot of inbox]

and the actual number of comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160813/is-there-a-way-to-present-better-criteria-for-closing-a-question#comment467631_160813) which is 3

[image: snapshot of comment section]

I have not noticed it being correct, the first time I saw it I wanted to report a bug but saw some notes about deleted comments, but this has persisted or at least reoccurred twice now

Comment: That question has one deleted comment on it. My theory is that you got the notification when there were still 4 comments, but I'm not sure how the count is fetched for the notification.

Comment: The count is still incorrect as the message has noved down the list, so i am guessing it is canned with the full text, but i am fairly certain it was incorrect at the last notification. So this miscount survived a second notification