# Latest event is only shown in inbox without any addition info

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

[Old design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161112/incorrect-comment-count-in-inbox)  - Here it says 4 comments on an X question.

The old design is better. Why it is changed?

I got 4 comments and 2 answers but only the latest is shown.

[image]

[Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1184897?noredirect=1)

[Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/547651?noredirect=1)

noredirect' parameter use in those link?

Comment: Those are two different posts. If you won't get inbox item for each, you'll never know you got a comment or an answer. No bug here and the example you posted is totally not relevant.

Comment: In the old design, it says the total No. of comments for a post but now it is not.

Comment: Well in high traffic posts, it caused the post author to get hundreds of notifications, which are just noise and cluttering the inbox. If you want to see all the comments and replies in one place, there's "responses" tab in the user profile for that. Inbox should be for things that require your immediate attention.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask What about the old design? It neatly explains

Comment: What old design? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Got a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is by design. You'll usually need to read the comments in the context of the post (and perhaps older comments as well), so it doesn't really matter how many new comments there are. Note that the number of new comments (or other events) *will* be correctly shown in the red badge.

The `noredirect` parameter is there to prevent situations where you're somehow not logged in on the target site and the question is closed as a duplicate; without the parameter, you would automatically be forwarded to the 'original' question, i.e. the duplicate 'target'. That would be very confusing.

Comment: At least it should be separated from old comments by a line.

Comment: If so, the link should be for the first comment. As there is no meaning in reading in reverse order

Comment: And the notification should be clubbed for a similar event

Comment: What about for answers?