# Review queue tutorial

Tags: feature-request, review, tutorials

*Personally, I feel sometimes confused when rejecting suggested edits, which one option to choose between `Invalid edit`, `Radical change` or even `Vandalism`...*

I propose, that it would be nice to have an option (eventually obligation) to get trough some tutorial per review queue, when I get enough reputation to review. The tutorial should show typical scenarios, how to deal with various *(at least one per type)* kinds of good/wrong posts. Actually, I can imagine it as a serie of few resolved reviews such as you get on `review-audit`.

Comment: Related request: [Add a link to the more detailed “How-to-review” meta posts in Review pages?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155770/158605)