# Add references to meta posts in privilege wikis

Tags: feature-request, privileges

I would like to suggest that we add references to meta posts in the privilege wikis. Currently, the wikis are very lacking on the details on *the appropriate way* to use the tools/make use of the privilege (review tools, 10k tools, protect post, deletion, etc.).

I don't think that this is a new suggestion. At least, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155770/add-a-link-to-the-more-detailed-how-to-review-meta-posts-in-review-pages) is a more specific request, regarding review privilege.

The tools are there, but the more specific issues are only accessible if the user frequents meta site. Sometimes, it doesn't appear to be an issue until the user is pointed out by other users. It also saves time when all the relevant meta posts are together in one place.

**Update**

I will list the privilege wikis that I have improved here as time goes:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: This is a great idea!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds reasonable. If you find an appropriate question, you can suggest an edit to the tag wiki here on MSO (only):

[image: pointing out edit button]

If and when it is approved, it will eventually be pushed out to all sites, so be sure the faq post applies to all sites, not just M/SO.