# How do I review tag wiki edits for new tags?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When reviewing in the edit queue, I constantly come across tag wiki edits like the following example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1792156

The tag wiki that the person wrote was entirely about dialog boxes

I personally don't think that we need a tag about dialog boxes, but If we did, than I have nothing against the edit in question.

I personally don't know what to do with these, so I normally just skip them.

How do I handle these new tag edits?  What traits am I looking for?

Comment: A separate issue, but that _particular_ example is copypasta [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_box) anyways.

Comment: But the source is cited at least.

Comment: @Mike: It is? I don't see it.

Comment: @Josh - at the bottom it lists 3 references, first one says `[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_box`

Comment: @Mike: Those are Markdown links; to call them a list of sources seems like a stretch to me, especially since they're not visible in the rendered wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dialog/info Further, for the second two, it doesn't matter that they're listed, because those sources don't allow verbatim use of their content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a number of steps I take when reviewing tag wikis:

1. The first thing I do is check to see if it is copied text without a source.  Sometimes it [should be obvious from the wall of text](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1785564#./1785564?&_suid=136441465043706884759955229218), but it's also pretty easy to confirm; just copy-and-paste into Google, and if you get any hits in the first four or five links, **reject** as "Copied Content".
2. If it's not copied text, see if it follows the [Tag Wiki guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and is helpful or [not](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1790775#./1790775?&_suid=1364414514515015828606307002074).  If not, **reject** as "Excerpt/Wiki Not Helpful"
3. Not bored yet?  Good!  If it's not copied *and* it appears to be helpful, make sure the text actually applies to the tag.  In the case of an ambiguous tags, make sure someone [isn't assigning a single meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1781559#./1781559?&_suid=1364414742375029807978092581344) to a tag that is currently has multiple meanings.  If this is the case, **reject** with a custom message.
4. Assuming you've made it this far, go look at some of the recent questions for the tag.  If the tag wiki seems to match up with the questions being asked, and it appears to be useful (or you're familiar with the subject matter and it *is* useful and correct), go ahead and **approve** it.
5. Still not sure?  Just **skip** it, and move on.

For me, I end up skipping or rejecting far more than I approve, but I think it's appropriate to take your time on reviewing these.  Do I spend too much effort on reviewing these?  Maybe, but I know there's a very good chance I'm not mis-approving something.

Comment: That's about as much work as it takes to actually write a good tag wiki

Answer (score 0):

While in that queue, you are reviewing the tag edits. If that's correct (it isn't now), you should just accept that edit.

But if you don't like the tag (e.g. you don't think it belongs on SO), you go to this meta site and create a question in which you tell us why you think the tag should be removed. You need to tag this with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) or [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms). The community will respond on that question and a moderator/10K+ user will create a tag synonym or delete the tag.

Comment: This one is not correct, it should have been rejected for plagiarism.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do say that: ("If that's correct (**it isn't now**) [...]"( I posted a general answer to these cases, because the starter asked a general question, not specific about that specific case.

Comment: Just making it *more* explicit.