# Edit a tag info if original author is not active anymore

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

I wrote a pretty detailed tag wiki (over 800 words) for Kotlin but it seems like the original author of this tag wiki is not active anymore as he was last seen in April.

Is there any way my edit can still be approved for example by an administrator or something like that?

Comment: You have made a common mistake made by most new tag wiki editors: you've explained what Kotlin is. That is not where tag wiki's are for. Tag wiki's should explain which questions should be tagged with it, so which topics you encounter in Kotlin are OK and which are maybe not. If I would have had review rights on CR I would have rejected that edit, based [on this review guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173871), primarily for not following [tag wiki guidelines](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/). Maybe you're lucky as you got already 1 approval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tag wiki edit suggestions go into the suggested edits queue just like any other suggested edit.

These get approved by the community (if the OP doesn't get to them first).

Whether the OP is around or not is not relevant.

Comment: But it says that it will be peer reviewed. Doesn't that mean that the OP first has to accept the edit or am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: Indeed - reviewed by your peers, the other users of this site. Which the OP is one of.