# How old does a question have to be for it to be a late answer?

Tags: support, review, late-answers

Kind of feel silly asking this but...I like reviewing, it's fun. At the time of this post I've reviewed 297 First Posts, but only 30 Late Answers, primarily because Late Answers appear less often. This got me thinking:

**How old does a question have to be, for an answer by a new user to be considered late?**

The Reviewer badge has been awarded 3720 at the times of this post. It would be interesting to see a breakdown of the total for the different types.

Ps. Sorry if this is a duplicate, I *did* look before I posted. If this information is available, I'm not aware of it, please share.

Comment: I got the steward badge for late post and it was awfully longer to get than the First Post one! I needed to check the wholeeeee day to get 20 late, and like in 1-2 hours you can get 20 in first posts

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question, but you can use [an old script of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329465/295232) to filter Reviewer badges by type, and find out how many have been awarded for the Late Answers queue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answers posted at least 30 days after the question was asked (when posted by a new user, i.e. one with [50 reputation or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/165773)) are considered "late" for the purpose of that queue.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it possible to see a breakdown of the amount of times that the Reviewer (and those similar) badge has been awarded?

Comment: Are only late answers by new users reviewed?  Or are all late answers?  If it is the former, is there a reason why you decided not to review all late answers?

Comment: Probably because those tend to be the most unpredictable, @psubsee2003. They can bring something new and fresh to a question that's been neglected, or just as easily reflect a confused new user struggling to work with an unfamiliar system (and failing badly). Oh, spammers are also somewhat over-represented among late-answerers.