# Is it possible to find users who earned a review badge for a specific queue?

Tags: support, review, badges, review-badges

It's possible to see all users who have earned a specific badge. For instance, I could go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478 to see all users on Stack Overflow with the Reviewer badge. The 3 reviewing badges (Custodian, Reviewer and Steward), can be awarded multiple times, once for each queue. I haven't found a way to find users who earned a specific badge for a specific queue, e.g. users who earned Steward for reviewing First Posts. I've checked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#188732) and didn't find a solution.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is this [from your first link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats) or [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), etc. but it's only the Top Users (and yourself, if you've done any today) for one specific queue, not everyone. Any answers forthcoming might be useful to add to the [Review Queue FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this information seems to be available only on the badge pages, I threw together a quick [userscript](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/review-badge-filter/review-badge-filter.user.js) ([direct install link](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/raw/master/review-badge-filter/review-badge-filter.user.js)) to add the filter options.

**Warning**: browsing through the 630 pages of the Reviewer badge on Stack Overflow took half an hour. Use with caution!

---

[image]

Comment: I have completed my 250, and Review badge turned into steward, And i dont even got review badge yet