# Is there a way to ask for some feedback on a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, review

As before recently, none of my edits ever got rejected, and now there's something like three in a row, I would like to know if there is a way to get some feedback on the reason why some suggested edit was rejected.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2181292), if I am not completely mistaken, the word "full" should better be replaced with the word "regular", as a FULL JOIN is something quite different from a "regular"/inner join described in the beginning of the answer. Nevertheless, this suggested edit was rejected, so I'm apparently missing something.

So I would be grateful for both an explanation for what I am doing wrong and for an advice on an appropriate way to contact the reviewers, if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By posting a question here, you're already asking for feedback... congratulations :)

---

In terms of *why* your edit got rejected, FWIW, I disagree with the other answer and would have accepted your edit. Whilst you do post additional information, it complements the existing answer well. You're providing a small snippet of extra information.

The most important thing is you're correcting terminology in the answer. You're also fixing all problems in the post by fixing the typo as well.

If the post owner didn't like your post, he can rollback the edit. That's what the functionality is there for.

I would hedge a bet that most (all?) of the users who rejected your edit have no experience in SQL, and found rejecting your edit easier than skipping, or by actually verifying your "full" -> "regular" edit was correct.

This is, unfortunately, part of the game with suggested edits. Plenty get rejected that should have been approved, and vice-versa. I myself got a [few](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/419) [rejected](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/421) a few days ago on another site, which annoyed me greatly.

Comment: The typo was correct, the full ->  regular was also correct.  Had he stopped there I also probably would have accepted it.  The paragraph he added though clearly belongs as a comment, and as such the edit needs to be rejected.

Comment: Yes, I would have rejected it.

Comment: @Servy: If the edit had simply been the addition of the paragraph, then I agree with you; a comment would have been best. However, given that the post has been improved overall, and that the ability to rollback exists, and given the paragraph adds information to the post which isn't *harmful*, I don't understand the *need* for rejection.

Comment: @Matt Adding helpful content along with content that isn't appropriate and shouldn't be rejected doesn't make the bad content good.  If you accept it then the OP has no way of knowing that what they didn't isn't appropriate and they'll only continue to do it again and again.  If you really wanted to you could 'Improve' the post to remove the comment, but the edit should still be rejected.

Comment: @Matt Well, it clearly looks like the current vox populi is against us. Thank you very much for the word of support. (I still think that _improving_ an answer can not be a wrong thing, and rejecting such an improvement without contributing to the answer is essentially evil ))

But this is life. Again, thank you -- and I am very sorry for your edits being dropped. Actually, imho this policy may greatly discourage people from improving readability, but that's "the editor's choice", I suppose.

Comment: Oh, and both of the examples of those edits of yours that were rejected were rejected by the OP, not reviewers, so they're pretty bad examples of problems with reviewers.  You also haven't actually answered the OP's question, which is actually, "Where do I go to get feedback on a rejected edit?" and not, "Why was this edit rejected?"

Comment: @Servy: I was referring to the annoyance at getting edits which had good intentions being rejected. You answered one part of the OPs question (although I think he already knew that, or he wouldn't know the edit was rejected). I answered the second part in [my comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181704/is-there-a-way-to-ask-for-some-feedback-on-a-rejected-edit/181708?noredirect=1#comment552535_181704). The OP also asks "So I would be grateful for both an explanation for what I am doing wrong", which is what led to this answer.

Comment: @Matt You posted an answer as a comment and a comment as an answer.  You should be posting answers as answers, and you shouldn't be posting answers that don't answer the question.  Also note that I answered *all* of the aspects of the question in the OP, not just how to find the edit rejection reason.  Perhaps you didn't read my second paragraph.  You also say that the OP can roll back an edit if they don't like it; well, in both of the examples of edits that were rejected it was the OP.  So you think they shouldn't be rejecting the edit but can roll it back if they want?

Comment: @Servy: I fail to see how this answer isn't an answer. Flag it as NAA if you think as such. Furthermore, I don't see how it doesn't [answer the question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VjtEu.png). I'm not suggesting you didn't answer the full question? I don't even know what you final point has to do with anythingggggg (nor do I fully understand it).

Comment: @Servy: as an experiment, I have tried to follow your suggestion: [*](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2185791), and as for me, it looks more like something has changed at SO. Indeed, they are doing it again and again.

Probably I indeed should stop editing other people's answers trying to make it better. May be this will free some time of those who press "reject" without giving it a thought. May be they even will start adding some content instead.

Comment: @Matt You don't answer the question of: `Is there a way to ask for some feedback on a rejected edit?`  You answered it in a comment, but not in the answer.  For this to be *an answer* it should *answer the question*.  Apparently this is a hard concept to grasp.  As for my last point, you are asserting in your answer that you have a problem with rejections, listing two examples.  In both cases the author of those posts was the one to reject your edit suggestion.  You have said earlier that while you don't think a reviewer should be rejecting such an edit, the author can always rollback.

Comment: @ジョージ You should no assume that those rejecting are doing so out of malice or laziness.  One of those rejecting even took the time to write a custom rejection message explaining in more detail *specifically* why he felt that it should have been rejected.  The lazy reviewers are largely those that hit accept without even considering the validity of the edit.  Those reviwers have been the scourge of the system essentially since it's inception.

Comment: @ジョージ It's important for you to understand the purpose of the edit system.  The purpose is to help make an answer better *without changing the authors content or meaning*.  You shouldn't be adding entirely new information, or even fixing something you feel is a mistake if it's clearly the intent of the author that it be the way it is.  You should either comment or post another answer in such cases.  Now, as I've said, I would have accepted the second edit you've made, but it is a borderline case, and I can understand why others would reject it.

Comment: @Servy: I answered that part of the question in my comment (which I made before both mine and your answer). Didn't *really* see the need to repeat it in my answer when I came round to writing it, but have it your way. Yes. That's exactly what happened, and exactly what I said... so what's your point?

Comment: @Matt My point is it's not an example of problems with the review system.  You seem to be implying that it's examples of reviewers acting improperly and rejecting good edits.  If any reviewers *had* rejected those edit it would be, but none did.  The only reviewer on those edits approved it.

Comment: @Servy: [Do you read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181704/is-there-a-way-to-ask-for-some-feedback-on-a-rejected-edit/181708#comment552584_181708) (*I was referring to the annoyance at getting edits which had good intentions being rejected.*).

Comment: @Servy: As the person who has asked the question, and was indeed seeking for information, let me assure you that I have managed to read both the comment and the answer provided by Matt, and have found them both helpful and informative. I suppose your answer has another virtue of being formally correct, though the only _new_ information I got from it is that I should refrain from editing other people's answers, as the majority of the reviewers seems to get extremely annoyed by it. This is useful to know (and I'm serious), but this is not what I was asking for.

Comment: @ジョージ Matt told you what you want to hear, that he thinks your edits should have been approved, but I don't see how that's helpful.  It may give you warm fuzzy feelings, but it doesn't help you understand why your edits were rejected, or how you can properly leverage the system to contribute the content you would like to.  If the lesson you've learned is that the guidelines for editing are too complex for you to bother learning them, I can understand completely.  They are complex, and that's unfortunate.  I hope you still take the time to contribute to the site through other means.

Comment: @Servy: [this is really important to know and I have clearly missed that point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181704/is-there-a-way-to-ask-for-some-feedback-on-a-rejected-edit#comment552596_181708). Can you provide me with a reference to any sort of SO rules where this is clearly stated, so that I would be aware for the future that SO is so very much different from a wiki site? (I do not quite get the logic behind this rule, but this may be a subject for a different question.)

Comment: @ジョージ [Here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/). It's targeting reviewers as the audience, but you can still use it to judge what types of edits would be accepted and what rejected.  That you're thinking this is just like any other wiki site explains the source of your confusion.  SO isn't a wiki site (but it borrows aspects of them). There isn't just one answer that is the sum of all contributors. There can be many answers from different people, and as such you should ensure, when editing, that it's still the author's answer, just better, not "our better answer".

Comment: @Servy Can you be more specific please? I can find there a recommendation to leave alone the typos etc in the _question_, what makes sense to me; as for the _answer_, an additional hint would be helpful.

Comment: @ジョージ Unfortunately there isn't exactly a single detailed rulebook that you can use as the canonical source of what is right and wrong; that's just not how SE works as a format.  There aren't many rules at all, it's primarily guidelines, community consensus, etc. based on broad goals that are given.  Many more specific guidelines are born out of meta questions when they are in dispute; the guidelines are all of meta (I said this was hard, and I meant it).  It's a lot like a judicial system that way; it's all based on precedent set, not the laws themselves.

Comment: @ジョージ An important point to realize is that it's not the end of the world to have an edit rejected, just like it's not the end of the world to have a comment deleted or an post downvoted. The system works by giving feedback to most everything a user does, and expects users to continue actions that cause positive feedback and to discontinue actions that cause negative feedback. Do whatever you think feels right when it comes to edits, and only if one is rejected should you try to determine why and then alter your behavior accordingly. Trying to always get everything right here is...impractical.

Comment: @Servy so basically there is no such statement and this is just the current state of affairs. That is what I have initially deduced from Matt's answer, thank you. BTW, this makes the link you have provided looking a bit misleading. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ジョージ Where did I say that at all?  I'm saying that the guidelines used for reviewing edits are the aggregate of all of the related questions on meta; this makes finding information about any one specific case hard, and finding information about what all of the guidelines are virtually impossible.  The post I linked to is a recent effort to attempt to address that problem.  The behavior that I am describing *is* an important and well established principle of the review system on SO, and as you have seen yourself, it is established.

Answer (score 11):

You can go to the review page for any of your edits (rejected or accepted) by clicking the "suggested edit" link on the activity tab.  Each user who rejected it will have needed to supply a reason.

If you *still* don't understand why your edit was rejected, even after looking at that page, then the only real option available to you is to post a question on meta.

As for your example, the second half of the rejection reason is the relevant point:

> This edit is [...] an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Your edit should have been a comment instead.  The key point here is you were adding entirely new content, rather than improving the content that the author had posted.  If the author wished, *they* could have incorporated it into their post.

If you feel that your additions are significant enough and important enough that they shouldn't just be posted in a comment, then you could post them as another answer, but I don't see that as being the case for the example that you listed.