# Are there examples of good reviews and edits

Tags: discussion, review

This new reviewer would find it helpful to be able to view "good" edits and reviews from other users.  As a user of the site I have seen and received "good" and "less good" edits, but it would be helpful to view a repository of each instead of having to search through posts.

Does such a thing exist and I'm just not finding it?

Comment: There are guidelines for good edits and reviewing, but AFAIK there's no existing repository of examples

Comment: Related (but not a repository of example reviews): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing

Comment: Can you see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history)? It's the edit review history. Look at the edits that were unanimously approved (though they're not all shining examples).

Comment: @Kevin I just get `You have not reviewed any suggested edits yet.`

Comment: You probably have to have 2k rep then, sorry.

Comment: A good review, in general, will attempt to follow the principles laid out in @bfavaretto's link.  Not all edits will, though.  My personal advice would be to follow around those editors that are more vocal about the editing process/quality of edits than others, to see some examples of decent editing.  Or diamond moderators - they have to know how to edit questions in a good way, too.

Comment: Some of the review queue audits are known good cases. As far as I know there aren't any for edits, though.

Answer (score -1):

Most posts on Stack Overflow have been edited (I haven't checked this it's just a feeling)
You can click on the date above the editor's name to see the edit that was made.
If it was approved there is a very high likelihood it is a good edit.

Best way to learn.

> [image]

Comment: What guarantee is there that, given a specific approval of an edit, that the edit was actually *good*?

Comment: 5 people (if i am not mistaken) must approve an edit So if all of them thought it was good it's probably on par with SO standards. Where will we be if the community can not be trusted

Comment: It's 3 people, and there are robo-approvers out there.  There are also users with a notoriously bad string of edits, too.  Just because it was approved by three people with questionable review practices doesn't mean that the review was good.

Comment: So eliminate the review process altogether and only let mods approve reviews

Comment: Okay.  First, we're getting *way* off topic.  I'd love to talk with you about this in length at a later time, but I'm not in a place to do that right this instant.  Second, the sheer volume of content that has to be edited to meet standards would overwhelm the handful of moderators we have, bogging down their actual role of being human exception handlers.  Third, the review process *does* have people that take it seriously.

Comment: @Makoto I agree some people don't go through their review duty as you or me or Jeff would want but I credited OP with insight and I belive that 6 out of 11 approved edits is _good_ which makes a good place to learn. Maybe I should add he should go back in time where question has stabilized and there is a higher chance of _great_ edit?

Comment: Oh wow, 6 our of 11.  I was optimistic like you once...Anyway, I don't think that the metric that the edit was approved or that there was an edit on a post means that the edit was good.  Good is subjective to everyone, but in general, there are procedures and steps to improve the post which have been agreed upon by the community-at-large.  Not every post or edit follows that, so just saying, "This post was edited back in 2010, so it must be good!" is a *horrible, horrible* metric.

Comment: A post that was edited _multiple_ times since 2010 should be pretty good don't you agree? I mean it's the power of wiki.