# Guidelines for "Not an answer" flag

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I have been reviewing flags and the vast majority are flagged as "Not an answer". However, many clearly represent attempts to answer the question (even though they mostly fail with very poor quality answers).

So I disagreed and flagged them as "Invalid flags", but this almost always gets disputed.

I read [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) But this doesn't seem to answer my question. Am I correct what I'm doing or not?

Examples:

- [equivalent code of winforms in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105319/equivalent-code-of-winforms-in-wpf/17109945#17109945)
- [Trouble with Facebook open graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386973/trouble-with-facebook-open-graph/19273152#19273152)
- [DrawerLayout + ViewPager when cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531516/drawerlayout-viewpager-when-cached/19275133#19275133)

I can understand that these answers may not be good quality and could be flagged as such, but they are certainly "answers".

Comment: This is by design. If you flag a flag as "Invalid" it will be counted as *disputed* immediately. But it won't affect your flagging ability.

Comment: I thought of the same at some questions. I was just browsing through some questions and it was "not a question" While it obviously was. I dont get it either. Maybe some people who dont understand what a question is?

Comment: Thanks - this makes no sense to me why it should be like that though.