# What is the purpose of the new Site Self-Evaluation Review category?

Tags: feature-request, beta-sites, documentation, site-evaluation

I spotted this [Site Self-Evaluation](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) category as a [History Stack Exchange Review](https://history.stackexchange.com/review) category today. However, it is not clear what content will appear here, or what tasks reviewers are meant to perform. Can someone provide some guidance?

Comment: Additonal on the review workflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180577#180577

Comment: @rene: I actually ran a Google search first for this, and scanned through all questions that were suggested as I typed in the title. Perhaps a few more questions pointing to the answers would be helpful.