# See what happens to skipped reviews

Tags: support, review

I have recently received the privilege of reviewing First Posts and Late Answers on Stack Overflow.  I have read [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538), which was mildly helpful in helping me become a better reviewer.  What I feel would most help me learn become a better reviewer would be to see how a more experienced reviewer would handle the same post that I am reviewing.

Given that context, if I skip a review, is there a way to see how the next reviewer handled it?  I've been copying the link to the post and seeing if I can see how it was handled, but this does not seem to be a robust method.

Comment: +1 Even as a moderately experienced user, I'd like to be able to learn this way too.

Comment: With a title like this, I originally expected this to be a demonstration of something that was missed and the ill consequences thereof. "See what happens when you skip a review!?", that sort of thing, haha. The idea here doesn't sound bad, though.

Comment: @GraceNote Yes, I was trying to maximize page views. :)  Perhaps even better would have been "Have you tried this 1 weird trick to improve your reviewing?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Becuase you skipped the review you don't have a handy direct link to it from the activity/reviews tab in your user profile, so you'll have to fish for it.

When on the reviews page for whichever queue you're dealing with, simply select the *history* tab:

[image]

Clicking on the review action on the right hand side will take you to the review with the details of each reviewer:

[image]

You should maybe feature request that skipped reviews are included in a user's activity tab?

Comment: This doesn't answer how to look at skipped reviews, though admittedly that's not really possible without manually keeping track of each review you've skipped.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That is true. Even getting the subsequent history of an edit you performed an action on takes a few clicks.

Comment: @slugster This might not work for <10k users. We cant see review history for other users.

Comment: @slugster Thanks for the suggestions.  Regarding your question, I am new to these things: Does is make sense for me to edit this post to add a feature-request tag?

Comment: @mbroshi I would craft up a new more specific "question", and tag it as a `feature-request`. Make sure you include good reasons why it should be done, maybe even propose where or how it's implemented. Members will then vote/comment/answer and if it's good you might see it implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get better at reviews is just to find one or two smart, high-character users who do reviews frequently.

For example, take this user:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/109702/slugster?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Just go to the reviews page in his/her profile, and open up the reviews he/she has done, and start learning from there.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is the possibility of cognitive bias. You see that another (supposedly "better") reviewer approved/rejected, and think "Oh, that's what I would have done," without giving it as much actual thought as you normally would. It's a bit different than looking at it "blind" first, then coming back to see what others said. Not saying it's a bad idea in general, it just might not help for those tricky ones you decided to skip.

Comment: Heh, I've got lots of character, I'm not sure if it's *all* good :) But to summarise, I reject or improve a good proportion of the suggested edits I review. Be discerning - the only way for a bad post to get worse is to apply a bad edit.