# Do I really need to add "useless" questions in order to interact?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have decades of coding history in my pocket. Still I have many of areas in which I am looking for answers.

When Google sends me here to this platform its mostly a good result.
Thus that means someone else has already had a similar question - and even the answers.

Sometimes I want to rate an answer as "best" or "not that helpful", or I want to contribute with my own answer to that. The current rules state a minimum of 15 points reputation for up voting an answer and even more for down voting and responding with a comment.

But guess what? When registering I start with just 1 reputation - that is not enough to do anything. Do I really have to fill up your platform (each flavour?) with some 3 "dummy" questions first, before I am able to interact in a human being meaningful fashion? At least I can not see any other way of achieving the system of accepting me with all my knowledge and understanding of the topics I have dealt with in the past decades.

Comment: the system tells me i am not allowed to answer.

Comment: What is the exact message? It is possible you have a bad answering record which got you answer banned.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: unless a post is protected, there is no minimum reputation limit on answering. What is the error you get?

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: you were able to [post this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403841/convert-12-bit-bayer-image-to-8-bit-rgb-using-opencv/24014562#24014562). Please don't use answer posts as comments, however; using `@name` doesn't work in answers and the intended recipient was never notified.

Comment: i can not remember that i deleted anything from my answers. yet i was told to have those 15 reps first before rating up other items.
the message i got was sort of a spam checker. i am really not doing any spam. and i dont see any item where i gave some real off-topic or similar response that would urge lots of people doing a massive down rating.

my typical topics are coding related - no idea at the moment what special minimum limits for answering are placed there. (i dont want to join a Mickey Mouse exchanges just to collect 200 reputations there.)

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: also, you made a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3423146/alexander-stohr?tab=reputation) that earned you a little reputation. You don't need many more of those to get to +15 allowing you to vote.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: Voting requires +15 to assure you have a minimum amount of experience *with how the site works* and to prevent fraudulent users from creating additional accounts just to gain votes quickly. It is really not hard at all to gain +15.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: you didn't share what error message you got, however. If you created a lot of 'comments' in answer posts, then you could have received an answering ban because too many of your answer posts got deleted. If so, you'll have to re-gain the trust of the community by offsetting those deleted answers with better quality contributions; e.g. suggested edits and good quality questions.

Answer (score 10):

No you don't have to ask questions just to gain reputation. You can instead create good answers, or you can earn reputation by making editing suggestions too.

Or you can join *another site* in the Stack Exchange network, and earn 200 points there. Once you do you get a [100 point association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) on any other account in the network, giving you enough reputation to vote up and comment everywhere. Perhaps you have interesting questions or helpful expertise in [other subjects](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that can net you those 200 points easily.

We need to have these limits in place because we want you to get to know how the platform works first, and to keep spammers and cheaters out. As such you need to have shown some minimal participation first.

Comment: Really, i would like to answer - it just does not work. Thus no way of getting any reputation by that.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: Even with 1 rep, new accounts can answer, *except* on [protected posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), which require a minimum of 10 reputation *earned on the same site*.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: what question did you try to answer, and what was the error message you got?

Comment: 101 rep is only enough to *up*-vote.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I never ment to imply you could downvote with that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:

I got this message:
"We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."
http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

i am at this part of exchange and at least edits seem to work there - so getting 2 points per edit seems to work in a reasonable time. i have overseen that option until now. it's taking a bit of time, not a 200 reputation points long time.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912282/opencv-2-3-with-qt-4-3-7/6912537#6912537

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: right, then you have received an answer ban; you'll have to follow the help center advice there. I am not sure the association bonus is going to help you there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters given above, is this question a dupe of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: the help center sends me vicious circles as soon as i click on the bottom link for more information on bans. it simply ends up on the very same page. so my knowledge and ability to deal with the subject does not increase.

Comment: i followed the advice and look after other peoples post with proposing edits (as probably this is the only thing i can do right now). i proposed additions and corrections and tags. guess what...? the additions like telling why a compiler decides to raise some error were rated "too far from original post". i did corrections of a few things and some got approved (not totally looked the whole list. and i further added obviousely missing tags and others told me "that is not sufficient".and the result

Comment: Getting rep is not the ultimate goal of this site. Being able to upvote and downvote isn't either. The true purpose of this site is _getting your questions answered_. If you don't have any questions, then why are you here in the first place? So far it sounds like you're making a mess of things. Edits for the sake of edits, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: yes, edits need to be addressing most, if not all issues with a post. You are also putting reviewers through work, so make it worth their while.

Comment: @gnat: yeah, I'll dupe hammer this.

Comment: and the result now is that after about some 10 of such non-abusive, kind and friendly, just discuss-able edits there a limit of rejections were hit - i can not even edit anymore. What shall id do if any thing that can be a valid edit is voted in a manner where even search tags wont get trough that are 100% valid for the topic and would much benefit people searching such topics by tags.

Comment: a) i see no big reason to reject tags that are good
b) i see no reason why a discussable edit that got rejected results in a penalty. there must be something in between black and white - you might call it grey.
c) i see not much of a reason of recommending any editing when editing (even when done in the very best and most helpful intent and even fashion) is the biggest trap for getting penalties.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: suggested editing bans are temporary, meant to help you learn what makes good editing suggestions. If you are blocked now, sit it out. Read up on suggested edits both here and on http://meta.stackoverflow.com. I do appreciate that you are doing your best to be part of the community here, but try to take the time to learn about how he site works too!

Comment: even small contributions can have a positive sign. a negative rating for that is simply the wrong direction. knowledge accumulates in smaller steps more often than in larger steps. so does every Q&A system. a first quick answer, a second more precise one, a third conclusive one that covers all remaining white items. - nope, small is never evil. but your rating system treats it that way - or better say the people that are applying it seemingly behave like they would never have some other choice of BASHING DOWN THE EVIL.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr to increase chances for your edit suggestions to get through, it would help to see how reviewers of these are expected to think when deciding whether to accept or reject. This is described in details here: [Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/165773) (edit ban is temporary indeed, I've been banned like that myself 2 or 3 years ago, it took only a week and was very helpful as it taught me to be more careful)

Comment: as the site wants review the text reviewers should see that they might see big and small contributions. so the big ones are bigger review work, the smaller ones are smaller work portions. to my present understanding of a review, such step shall rate the quality than the length. the review efforts roughly do correlate to the provided input. for rating "big" or "small" i dont need a human, but the human is unavoidable when it comes to quality (correctness and sufficient clear expression of the item). stack exchange has an automated size checker in place. thats why reviewers dont have to judge it

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: You also expect you to work for those 2 points; too many people would go around only adding tags and fixing individual small spelling mistakes. If you put as much work into your suggested edits as you put in this conversation, really, you should be fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - believe me i put works in that. and believe me when it was a small change it still was really not a typo i dealt with. its like some one talking about the depth of the design of OS X and then he was only adding "shell" as a tag then this is ...ehm... an item where editing in an extra tag will definitely worth the short check and click by a reviewer. - sometimes i file like questioning a system that is not working to its best performance is simply needed. even stack exchange can do better with really only a little bit of fine tuning in its review process design.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr: You are being **too verbose** here. This is not the place to discuss the workings of the suggested edit review system, really.