# Review Low Quality Posts for very old posts

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts

If this is a duplicate please point me to a good answer for an existing question as I was not able to find one (and I've looked through a few including the most linked to [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029)).

Sometimes in the "Review Low Quality Posts" there are old posts of bad quality. What am I expected to do in such case? The thing is that for such posts there are only two choices under "Delete":

- No comment needed
- This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

and there is a text in footer

> This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary. If you think it could be fixed, go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.

So am I supposed to just vote for deletion without comments? Or should I leave a hand-made comment with my opinion for other reviewers? Or should I not vote for deletion of such posts?

Example: [Not ever downloaded from Webservice item is displayed in the ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145074/not-ever-downloaded-from-webservice-item-is-displayed-in-the-listview/38146697#38146697) where OP essentially asks a new question or modifies the original one as an answer to his own question.

Answer (score 2):

If it deserves deletion, delete it silently.

If it can be salvaged by you, fix it. If it can be salvaged, but *not* by you, leave a comment that explains better.

If it's basically fine, let it stay on the site.

The only difference is that newer posts benefit more from most of the auto-comments, but those are never required anyway, and from time to time a post (new or old) needs a different comment. Criteria for deletion stay essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are not directly deleting the post you are recommending post for deletion if a post seems not salvageable then you can recommend deletion, comment option is not there, one reason I think is that old posts are less likely to get attention of user.

From: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> Answers with zero or negative score that receive six recommend
>   deletion reviews in the low-quality-posts review queue are
>   automatically deleted “in review”. Answers can be kicked into this
>   queue either automatically or with very low quality and not an answer
>   flags, and can be removed from the queue if enough looks OK reviews
>   are cast against them.