# Bug or Feature in Audit "STOP! Look and Listen."? Answer to review in audit not visible outside audit

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, late-answers

I just got access to the review queues (late answers). I tried to be thorough and opened the question in a new tab, since the answer I should review was odd and I thought maybe someone just copied an old comment or something. I wanted to see the whole context to write an informed comment to that answer since the user who committed it was new.

The question didn't have the answer I saw for review nor did it have any other comments on it from other reviewers and I thought: "Oh, thats weird."
I waited some time and reloaded the tab with the question - the answer did not show up, so I clicked on "No action needed." (Obviously, the answer was not visible like in reviews I did previously, so why bother? And I did not skip it since I did a review after all.)

I got the

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. This answer was of very poor quality, and needed
>   significant improvements to be useful – passing over such posts hurts
>   the ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to
>   fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very
>   low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

dialog.

I think that the answer to review is not shown under the question when having an audit is a bug. Or are there real situations where the item to review is not visible for the reviewer outside of the review tab?

Furthermore now I'm uncertain how to do reviews. Usually when I see a poor answer or question which was already downvoted 5 times and has 3 similar comments about poor quality I press "No action needed" too. I don't want to skip, since I did a review and I think a fourth poor quality comment does not add any more value.

Comment: The audit presented you with a previously deleted answer, to see if you would handle it how it was previously handled. You did notice that something was up. Good! That's the point of audits, to make sure you're paying attention to your reviews. You got tripped up, however: You thought "No Action Needed" because the answer truly needed no action and was already deleted. However, you should have pretended the answer was not deleted and acted as if it was still on the page. This trips a _lot_ of people up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think that the answer to review is not shown under the question when having an audit is a bug.

No, it's not a bug.  It's a deleted post, and since you don't have 10k rep, you can't see deleted posts.

> Usually when I see a poor answer or question which was already downvoted 5 times and has 3 similar comments about poor quality I press "No action needed" too.

Then you're doing the wrong thing, and the audit is correctly informing you of this.  If a post is a bad post, you shouldn't be doing nothing.  As the audit message says, you should be acting on the post with votes, comments, edits, comment votes, flags, etc.  Other people having voted on the post doesn't mean you can't vote.  If all of the earlier comments cover everything there is to cover, upvote those that apply, and if they don't cover everything, add anything that you feel you have to add.  If the post is that bad (and it is, if it's an audit) then the post also merits flags; you should be casting those flags.

Comment: I found some more guidelines for reviewing https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing