# Editing duplicate list in Reopen Votes review queue should count as a Leave Closed result

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen, dupehammer

When I'm reviewing a duplicate question in the Reopen Votes review queue with a tag for which I have a gold badge, I can edit the duplicate list. That's nice, but it leads away from the review page; I have to return to the review queue myself (potentially loading another review item, unless I use the back button) and click Leave Closed. Since it doesn't make sense to reopen the question after editing duplicates, the system could as well remember my choice and show me the next review item.

To quote from the [reviewing guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450/377214):

> If the question is closed as a duplicate, but is instead a duplicate of a different question from the one specified, **review as "Leave Closed"** and flag for a moderator or ping a gold-badge user to have the duplicate target changed.

I'm not sure if a screencast/screenshots help clarifying the issue but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH50u.jpg) is one.