# Skip spam LQP review audits or click on Recommend deletion

Tags: discussion, review, spam, review-audits, low-quality-posts

From the [reviewing guidelines FAQ for low quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/525172):

> - [QA] **Spam or rude/abusive posts:** click the "link" to the post, and cast its corresponding flag. **Do not** "close", "recommend close", "recommend deletion", or "delete" in the queue. This will make sure that the appropriate penalties are levied, and as authors are able to undelete answers deleted in this queue, they can restore the spam or offensive post without a trace. Once back in the review queue, **skip** the review item.

OK, we should skip spam in the Low Quality Posts review.

But the review audits are just answers deleted for spam (at least on stackoverflow where those only consist of answers).

According to the FAQ, we should click on the question and flag it for spam if we find a spam answer but we obviously cannot do that for those audits.

Currently, I click on `Recommend deletion` and select `No comment needed` when reviewing a spam answer that I cannot find when clicking the `link` button and flag it for spam and skip it if I can find the answer using the `link` button.

Is that (`Recommend deletion`) the recommended behaviour for unavailable (and obviously spam) answers or should we just skip all LQP review audits?

Comment: Using spam as review audits in LQP is something I brought up as part of my user research interview with Lisa Park earlier this year. This should hopefully be fixed as part of the upcoming improvements to the review queues.

Comment: I hope so. I think it is a joke that there is no spam/flag option and the audits are only spam...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you choose 'Recommend Deletion' or 'Skip' for a review audit. You're paying attention, that's all that matters. If you want more progress towards a [Steward badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward), choose 'Recommend Deletion'; if the queue is long and you want every one of your 20 daily reviews in that queue to really make a difference, choose 'Skip'.

(It might not be obvious, but not skipping a review audit both counts towards the badge progress and towards the daily maximum of 20 reviews per queue.)

Comment: And since passed audits are completely disregarded when imposing automatic review suspensions, it really doesn't matter.