# How can we prevent or discourage people from closing questions about which they know little or nothing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

There is not a week that goes by that I do not see a question that was closed for "**This question needs details or clarity**" *and yet the question is perfectly clear to me.*  My hypothesis is that this happens mainly because (perhaps overzealous) reviewers see a question they know little or nothing about, and assume that because they don't understand the topic that the question requires "details or clarity."

For now, I will give just one example:    [**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317362) is tagged [[matplotlib]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib) and [[mplfinance]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mplfinance).  To anyone who has knowledge of those two packages, this question is perfectly clear.

Personally, when reviewing questions, I try to be very careful not to comment or vote on topics about which I do not have some significant expertise.

*It seems to me that only people with a strong knowledge of a topic are qualified to say whether or not a question really does require additional details or clarity.*

My question here is whether we can come up with a way to discourage those with little knowledge of a topic from voting to close questions on that topic?

- Perhaps there should be an easy way to start a discussion with those who voted to close.  This could be a way to get clarity about which part of the question they don't understand.
- Alternatively, there should be an easy way (for both the questioner and other reviewers) to send a message to the closers, requesting that the question be re-opened to allow those with the required expertise to decide if the question *actually* requires details and clarity.

Comment: I feel this would be better off if posted on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com), since it seems rather specific to SO.

Comment: @cigien  I didn't realize that there was a separate Meta for stack overflow, but I do think that *possibly* this issue applies to all stack exchanges.  How to prevent non-experts from closing questions or voting them down just because they don't understand it.  Thanks.

Comment: That is possible, but you would need to make a much stronger case for that than you have here, with examples from various sites. At the moment, this seems very SO specific, and I think is much more appropriate there. And you definitely shouldn't cross post across metas. Since you've posted this question there, I suggest deleting this one.

Comment: I will look for examples from other sites.  I can't imagine that it doesn't happen to some extent on all SE sites, but it is difficult for me to assess because, as mentioned, I think a person has to be somewhat expert to truly know if details and clarity are needed.  That said, I will look around and see if I can find examples from other SE sites of which I am a member.

Comment: How do you know these people 'know little to nothing'? What I see way more often is people making some assumptions as to what they think the question probably is about, and writing an answer based on those assumptions. That doesn't mean the question is actually a good, clear, detailed enough one for Stack Exchange.

Comment: from my perspective, i don't think the question is unclear, but what it is... is inconsiderate of answerer's time. Anyone who wants to answer that question has to come up with their own chart + data to demonstrate it. it's not much code, wouldn't have been difficult to include.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell  - I agree that I see what you have describe also quite a bit.  This is another topic.  And I don't know for sure that they know little or nothing (which is why I called it my **hypothesis**) however for topic areas about which I *am* an expert, if someone asks for clarity (without commenting as to what aspect they need clarity on) and I think the question is perfectly clear, then I can only hypothesize that they don't know much about the topic.

Comment: @KevinB  I disagree that the person has to come up with their own chart.  The answerer did do that.  But it is not at all necessary.  They could have simply pointed the OP to the appropriate API call to do what they wanted (which is what I would have done if answering the question.  Where the question ***is*** inconsiderate, is that if the user had merely spent 15 to 20 minutes perusing the documentation for the package, they would have found the answer.

Comment: The "Needs details or clarity" reason is also used when the question seems fairly basic but it doesn't provide enough context to determine *why* the OP has to ask this question. Should they be studying a tutorial or textbook instead? Stack Exchange answers are supposed to supplement such resources, they cannot act as a replacement for them.

Comment: @PM2Ring > also used when the question seems fairly basic ... <  completely reasonable!  I would only argue that the average OP (especially if relatively new to SE/SO) may not realize that is what the closer is looking for.  In the example I gave, it is definitely the case that there exists a tutorial on the packages GH page that could have answered their question.

Comment: Well, we have to work with the close reasons that the sites provide. ;) Sometimes, people will post a comment to let the OP know why their question is inadequate, especially if the OP seems sincere & has done adequate research, but we aren't obliged to do that.

Comment: Also, if we need to guess what knowledge gaps led to the OP asking the question, then it's hard to write a proper focused answer. Similarly, if we need to write a whole textbook chapter to answer the question, it's not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We used to use the "Too broad" reason for such questions, and some people now use the "Needs focus" reason, but that doesn't seem appropriate when the OP has asked a single question.

Comment: @PM2Ring  Thanks for taking the time.  Your comments are definitely helpful for me understanding the process, as I have only recently gained close/open vote status.  Still trying to understand why some things get voted closed in, what seems to me, a very short amount of time, when I would have been inclined to add comments and encourage the asker for clarity that way.  It can be very discouraging, especially to new users, to have your question closed rather than having people help you with understanding how your question could be better.

Comment: I'm probably going to delete this question.  Clearly I am in the minority here and not understanding why its apparently regarded as a good thing to close questions quickly.  As mentioned in a previous comment, especially if someone is relatively new to SE or SO, if a question isn't up to snuff I would want to encourage and help the person understand how to write a better question.  The whole idea (it seems to me) of SE is the *exchange* of knowledge.  It seems to me that closing questions quickly, without comment, gives new users the impression that SE is a ruthless place.

Comment: On SO, there's a *lot* of traffic with a high percentage of bad questions, so the culture is to close poor quality questions so that they don't totally swamp the useful questions (i.e., questions likely to help many future readers). Feel free to post helpful comments to instruct & support OPs of bad questions, but you can't expect most regular answerers & curators to do so. On a smaller site (eg, Astronomy, where we might get a dozen questions on a busy day), people are much more inclined to help new OPs fix poor questions.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb Users who experience a closed question are given a banner which tells them why said question was closed, should they follow the links presented therein, as well as read the banner itself.  It isn't feasible to give every single person who doesn't read the site's guidelines individualized help, not to mention that if a particular user is hostile, adding a comment in that regard just invites revenge actions.  I've encountered users like that, and they do exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) - "Needs details or clarity - 
The text in the closing dialog is self-explanatory: **please clarify** ***your*** **specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.".

Comment: @Daedalus  what you are saying makes sense, and I agree that some users can be hostile, however my inclination is to give them the benfit of the doubt at the start.  I have learned a lot over the years from SE and SO in particular.  It is a valuble way for people to exchange knowledge and expertise.

Comment: @Rob  I have read those guidlines for review a while back.  I think it is time to re-read them.  It just seems to me that oftentimes questions are closed very quickly, which especially for new posters, can be very discouraging.  As mentioned in my previous comment I have gained a lot by interacting with others on SE and SO in particular.  And I would hope to encourage others to do so.  Imho SE should be an inviting and inclusive place.  Perhaps we don't allow questions to be closed until after 24 hours, to allow users a chance to revise if needed.

Comment: I sympathize with your concerns. The problem is there's no way to assert a user's expertise (the 3k reputation threshold only equates loosely to site experience). Now, if a close reason is wrong reviewers are expected to see that and choose *"Leave open"*. Good sense and conscientiousness are expected to prevail. The inverse is also true, frequently you have to make a judgement call where you're not 100% sure but the question gives enough indications the previous reviewer is right about his judgement call. I also take into account who the 1st close voter was, some users are consistent.

Comment: @bad_coder thanks for your comments.  definitely something to think about, as was my original intent in posting this question (perhaps I should have made that more clear).  I just think that the review process/guidelines could possibly be improved to make SE more inviting and inclusive to those who are new, but I'm not sure what the best answer is.  As you say, the inverse is also true.

Comment: Well if you want to be more inviting and inclusive to users, a great start would be to not assume they know little/nothing...and at least try and get a proper explanation/understanding of why things were done the way they were done.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb the current problem, especially on SO, is the volume of incoming questions is overwhelming for the number of active reviewers. In 2020 over [425k questions were closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404558) with around 50% of items *"ageing"* out of the review queue before having a completed review. So if you see an excessively zealous closure it's frequently a tiered reviewer that might have made 1 wrong decision in 50. Anyway, the solution is casting a reopen vote and leaving a clear explanation in the comments to help reopen reviewers decide.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell  you made your point previously;  I will re-phrase my question.  I am certainly open to getting a better understanding of why people close questions as "unclear" while, at the same time, other people find the exact same question perfectly clear.  That is what is at issue here.

Comment: Question: Do you want your question answered or do you want your question to serve many visitors to come? In the former case this meta question is awesome in trying to accuse the reviewers of doing a poor job. In the latter case, your question isn't suited for all age categories. That is something only you can fix.

Comment: You've done two reviews on SO. Please go here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close and do 40 of them (that is the daily allowed allotment). Let us know how it went.

Comment: @bad_coder: And an astounding number of questions are deleted every year. [1.6 million deleted posts in 2020](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404558) and [1.4 million deleted posts in 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550) (presumably the majority of the deleted posts are questions).

Answer (score 18):

> . I am certainly open to getting a better understanding of why people close questions as "unclear" while, at the same time, other people find the exact same question perfectly clear. That is what is at issue here.

5 times out of 10, this is because the people to whom the question is perfectly clear are making assumptions: they're filling in the holes themselves with what makes sense in their minds, without feeling they need to check whether their assumptions are correct. They already 'know' the answer and just make the question fit that.

The other 5 times out of 10 it is most likely people don't realize the close reason is for *lacking **details or** clarity*, not just for being *'unclear'*. So, a question can be perfectly clear, but still lack the necessary details, and be closed for that same reason. This is most likely to happen with questions that e.g. lack a minimum reproducible example, or some explanation of what the OP tried to solve their problem and why/how that didn't work out.

> My question here is whether we can come up with a way to discourage those with little knowledge of a topic from voting to close questions on that topic?

You don't need to be a subject matter expert to see that a question lacks details. In case of [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317362), it's very obvious it lacks the [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6380541) and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), even to someone like me that only used SO regularly to find answers. That question lacks the details SO expects from a question.

As for discouraging (I like to think of it as 'preventing' though) a mistaken user from closing a question, such a system already exists. Closing a question requires more than 1 person, with exceptions for gold tag badge holders (who have proven they know about a subject by getting their gold tag badge) that can single-handedly close duplicates, and diamond moderators who can close every question single-handedly.

The other part of that system is called edits, comments, reopen votes, and meta. If you see a question that seems clear to you but obviously wasn't to others, edit it to fix anything that may have caused the closure in the first place, or leave a comment asking the post author to clarify and edit their post.

If you see a question that has enough detail according to current site guidelines to be kept open, vote to keep open in the close-vote queue, or vote to reopen if the question is already closed. And if you aren't 100% sure why a question was closed or if it should be reopened, post on the specific meta site.

Comment: "You don't need to be a subject matter expert to see that a question lacks details." - **Thank You** for saying that.  I could not agree more with that statement.